# Get a UTC timestamp

Tags: javascript, time

How can I get the current UTC timestamp in JavaScript?  I want to do this so I can send timestamps from the client-side that are independent of their timezone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript

Comment: Need a UTC timestamp specifically.  The problem is that Date.getTime() alone depends on client timezone.

Comment: No it doesn't. [Date.getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) returns a UTC timestamp.

Comment: @wizzard could you explain why `new Date(2019, 3).getTime() !== Date.UTC(2019, 3)` then? Thanks. Also, if I create a new Date with getUTC... I will never have the correct start of year, month etc...

Comment: @RomainVincent you actually should test with TZ: `Date.UTC(2021, 15, 18, 4) == new Date(2021, 15, 18, 0).getTime() > true` - I'm now at 4 behind UTC. See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58884821/986862

Answer (score 263):

```js
const timestamp = new Date().getTime()

console.log(timestamp)
```

For more information, see [@James McMahon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012173/237917).

Comment: Date.getTime() already returns the UTC timestamp. There is no need to apply an offset. See @james-mcmahon's answer below.

Comment: For me in my angular app it returns my local time, not UTC.

Comment: As a note, `getTime()` returns a Unix time-stamp adjusted for my local time instead of UTC. ie. `new Date(2016, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0).getTime()` returns 1451635200000 which is `8:00 AM Jan 1st 2016`.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell no, you are blaming the wrong guy here. `getTime()` returns the correct UTC number for a given input, it was the `new Date()` that returned the time in your local timezone - the midnight in the GMT-0800 timezone happened at `8:00 AM` UTC

Comment: thanks for the clarifications Aprillion! Finally I understand why people keep saying `new Date().getTime()` or `Date.now()` is UTC but when I try `console.log(new Date())`, it displays time in my timezone. The Date internally has the timestamp (milliseconds) in UTC (w/c is what is returned in `getTime()` or `now()`), and it also has "your timezone" information, so when the date is displayed, it automatically displays it in the correct (your) timezone. Try `new Date().toUTCString()` to see it in UTC. If you want, you can verify a return value of `Date.now()` here: https://currentmillis.com/

Comment: @Mon You should put your comment as an answer. The existing answers, while "correct", won't work for many scenarios.

Comment: This does not get the UTC date. I do not understand how this is accepted.

Comment: This is the correct answer! Why? Because "Jan 1, 1970, 00:00:00.000 GMT" is a singular immovable point in time from which the calculation is done as such it can not be more or less than the number of seconds elapsed since. as such it is in UTC, always.

Comment: As all people said, this method gives new Date() as my local zone not in UTC

Comment: @JordiEspada A few of the comments above have correctly noted that while `new Date()` produces a value in the local time zone, the subsequent call to `getTime` adjusts for that time zone, returning a UTC timestamp. See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) and [James McMahon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012173/221708) for reference.

Comment: @DanielSchilling Was my wrong interpretation, I supposed that new Date operation returns the time in UTC, but in fact the representation can be represented in UTC or local in function of the neededs.

Answer (score 179):

As [wizzard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260337/wizzard) pointed out, the correct method is,

```
new Date().getTime();
```

or [under Javascript 1.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now), just

```
Date.now();
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime),

> The value returned by the getTime method is the number of milliseconds
>   since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

If you wanted to make a time stamp without milliseconds you can use,

```
Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
```

I wanted to make this an answer so the correct method is more visible.

You can compare ExpExc's and Narendra Yadala's results to the method above at http://jsfiddle.net/JamesFM/bxEJd/, and verify with http://www.unixtimestamp.com/ or by running `date +%s` on a Unix terminal.

Comment: Date.now(); returns timestamp for my timezone, not UTC+0. So i have to modify it with new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

Comment: @LukasLiesis if you tested this by `console.log(new Date(timestamp))` then the timezone is a property of the Date object, not of the timestamp - the input must be in number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC in order for the Date object to display correct time in your local timezone... if you adjust the number, then the time will be incorrect

Answer (score 98):

You can use [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) method to get the time stamp at the UTC timezone.

Usage:

```
var now = new Date;
var utc_timestamp = Date.UTC(now.getUTCFullYear(),now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate() , 
      now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds(), now.getUTCMilliseconds());
```

Live demo here http://jsfiddle.net/naryad/uU7FH/1/

Comment: @ExpExc check closely, they are not the same. jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/naryad/uU7FH/1/

Comment: For me this works only if I use getUTCMonth, getUTCDate, etc. At least when compared to `$ date -u +%s`

Comment: The UTC timestamp on the jsfiddle link is incorrect. Actually your "Local timestamp" is the UTC timestamp and your "UTC timestamp" is the # of seconds between epoch UTC and your local time, which isn't really meaningful.

[Date.getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) automatically returns a UTC timestamp.

Comment: @wizzard UTC timestamp is the # of seconds between epoch (1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC) and UTC time. Local timestamp is the # of seconds between epoch and local time. `Date.getTime()` returns local timestamp where as `Date.UTC` returns the UTC timestamp.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) I linked to. Look at your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naryad/uU7FH/1/) timestamps and compare them to the current UTC timestamp [here](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/) (or using `$ date -u +%s` as suggested above). Why don't you try parsing your timestamps back to dates and see what you come up with?

Comment: Or heck, check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756120/utc-timestamp-in-javascript

Comment: Yeah @wizzard is right, this method is not going to give you the correct UTC time.

Comment: @JamesMcMahon Well, the docs say so https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC "The following statement creates a Date object using GMT instead of local time: `var gmtDate = new Date(Date.UTC(96, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0));`"

Comment: @Narendra Yadala, I think you are misunderstanding the docs, like wizzard said, compare the output of your method with the UTC timestamp at http://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Comment: @JamesMcMahon @wizzard OP wants timestamp at the UTC timezone not the local timezone. `new Date().getTime()` returns timestamp (number of milliseconds between epoch and local time) relative to the local timezone. Where as the `Date.UTC` returns the timestamp relative to UTC timezone (number of milliseconds between epoch and UTC time). Hope that helps. Editing the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: @NarendraYadala, Either I am completely missing something or your answer is still wrong. It doesn't match up the timestamp at unix time, which is showing the GMT (also know as UTC) timestamp. There is an explanation of what is going wrong here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/9756189/20774, "new Date(Y, M, D, h, m, s) treats its input as local time. If you pass in UTC time, of course you will get different results."

Comment: @JamesMcMahon My answer just assumes that the OP wants the unix time stamp at the UTC timezone and that is precisely what `Date.UTC` method does. `new Date().getTime()` gives unix time stamp at the local timezone. So what do I do, I create a current local date object using `new Date()` and then extract year, month, date, hrs, min, sec, ms from that object and pass it to `Date.UTC` method and that method returns the unix time stamp at the UTC timezone.

Comment: I don't understand why you're so unwilling to simply compare the results of your code to the current UTC timestamp and see that it does not work. You can argue all you want but the fact is it is wrong. We have tried to explain why it is wrong but you make no effort to understand. Abandon all hope, ye who enter here.

Comment: @wizzard I exactly know what I am doing here. Btw, what should I compare and with what? The output of `Date.UTC` is not the same as unix time stamp and I am well aware of this. Unix time stamp returns the local time stamp. OP wants the unix time stamp at the UTC timezone. They are obviously not the same values. Please read the comment of OP, "Need a UTC timestamp specifically. The problem is that Date.getTime() alone depends on client timezone. – babonk"

Comment: [Unixtimestamp.com](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/) shows the current UTC time stamp as well as your local time stamp. We are asking you to compare your output to the UTC timestamp. If you were returning the UTC timestamp, the values would be similar, but they're not, BECAUSE YOUR CODE IS WRONG.

Comment: @wizzard I have two timestamps here for january 12 10:30pm
PST 1610519400
UTC 1610490600

If you plug both of those into unix timestamp converter you will be able to see what OP wants.  

The first time stamp is January 12 10:30pm PST from EPOCH
The second timestamp is January 12 10:30PM UTC from EPOCH

Comment: This approach for getting UTC time is very helpful to get correct UTC date without time: `var now = new Date; Date.UTC(now.getUTCFullYear(),now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate())`

Answer (score 11):

"... that are independent of their timezone"

```
var timezone =  d.getTimezoneOffset() // difference in minutes from GMT
```