# getting UTC time in Seconds with javascript

Tags: javascript, utc

I need to get the utc time in secs ( for Wed Nov 07 00:50:28 GMT I need it to return: 1352249428 )

I have this code right now:

```
current_date = new Date()
var x_timestamp = current_date.getUTCSeconds();
```

but it's returning 28.00

Help. Thanks

Comment: Look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047616/get-a-utc-timestamp-in-javascript

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp

Comment: getTime()/1000 should do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `UTC` off your date object and dividing that result by 1000.