# Retrieve UTC Time in Javascript

Tags: javascript

We are currently using the following in our code to get the UTC Time:

```
    date.format("isoDateTime")
```

How do you get the UTC Time in javascript?

Comment: Posible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756120/utc-timestamp-in-javascript

Comment: Your question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047616/get-a-utc-timestamp-in-javascript

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date objects come with a [`toISOString()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString). Assuming `date` is your JavaScript [date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), you can simply call:

```
date.toISOString();
```

Answer (score 1):

`.toISOString()` is good for string. If you need JavaScript date object use

```
    var getUtcTime = function() {
        var d = new Date();
        return d.getTime() + d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

var d=new Date(Date.UTC(2013,10,09));