# ISO string to CST javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date in the format of ISO string

```
date = new Date ().toISOString()
```

which returns me "2015-12-08T14:03:36.129Z"

now i want to change this date to CST and want output like

December 23, 2015 11: 30 AM

Comment: Is the return value from `.toString()` close enough?

Comment: you should take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8047891/1114934

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a UTC Timestamp in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756120/how-do-i-get-a-utc-timestamp-in-javascript)

Comment: Like on deamentiaemundi's answer, I can't recommend [moment](http://momentjs.com/) enough. It is the de facto datetime library for JS, both client and server side.

Answer (score 1):

Note that CST is a single time zone that is UTC-0600. If you want daylight saving in the same zone, you'll need to program that yourself.

To get the time in any time zone, you can adjust the date's UTC time for the required offset, then just read the UTC values, like the following:

```js
function getCST(date) {
  var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
                'August','September','October','November','December'];
  var d = new Date(+date);
  
  // CST is UTC -0600 so subtract 6 hours and use UTC values
  d.setUTCHours(d.getUTCHours() - 6);
  
  return months[d.getUTCMonth()] + ' ' +
         d.getUTCDate() + ', ' +
         d.getUTCFullYear() + ' ' +
         ((d.getUTCHours()%12) || 12) + ':' +
         ('0' + d.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2) + ' ' +
         (d.getUTCHours() < 12? 'AM':'PM');
}

document.write("Current CST time is: " + getCST(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just format it yourself (assuming CST = north american central standard time = UTC - 6 hours)

```
function getCSTDate(){
  var months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June",
                "July","August","September","October","November","December"];
  var date = new Date();
  var meridian;
  var cstdate = "";

  date = new Date(
    date.getUTCFullYear(),
    date.getUTCMonth(),
    date.getUTCDate(),
    date.getUTCHours() - 6,
    date.getUTCMinutes(),
    date.getUTCSeconds(),
    date.getUTCMilliseconds()
  );
  meridian = (date.getHours() < 12)?"AM":"PM";
  //CST date example: December 23, 2015 11:30 AM
  cstDate =   months[date.getMonth()]
            + " "
            + date.getDate()
            + ", "
            + date.getFullYear()
            + " "
            + date.getHours()
            + ":"
            + date.getMinutes()
            + " "
            + meridian;

  return cstDate;
}
```

Obvious Problem with this approach: daylight saving time. You can do it by hand (doesn't change very often) or use something like [TimezoneJS](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js) or [MomentJS-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).

Comment: The new date can be set to 6 hours earlier simply by `date.setUTCHours(date.getUTCHours() - 6)`. But daylight saving boundaries will be an issue…

Comment: @RobG Yepp, that's shorter, admitted ;-) But I work on dates (no, that are fruits, datums?) as little as possible and I know why: too many chances to leave that scene with a perforated foot, way too many! I use a build-in function or a library if available and MomentJS seems to be a good solution for JavaScript.