# Shopify Time difference

Tags: time, shopify, difference

I am newbie to shopify, I have to display a time counter up-to 9 PM everyday. The logic includes to deduct current time from specified time and the difference time will display as counter(remaining time).

I am able to retrieve current timestamp in shopify using the code below

```
{% assign timestamp = 'now' | date %}
```

Now I have a date "21-03-2016 21:00:00" and wants to convert in timestamp but not able to get the solution.

Let me know if any one can help me in this. Thank You.

Comment: Can't use JavaScript for the purpose?

Comment: JavaScript will show local time I need to use UTC time zone that is why I am trying to use server date.

Comment: You'd want to check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047616/get-a-utc-timestamp-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

> Note that the value will be the current time of when the page was last
>   generated from the template, not when the page is presented to a user
>   if caching or static site generation is involved.

http://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/date/

Answer (score 1):

This is probably best done using Javascript, not pure-Liquid.  You generally want your pages to be as cache-able as possible for Shopify's servers to keep loading times as lean as possible.

You *will* want to use Liquid to compensate for timezones, however. You can get the store's configured timezone and drop that into a Javascript variable:

```
var timezone = {{ 1 | date: '%z' | json }};
```

The above liquid statement takes some arbitrary input, runs it through the date filter and outputs only the timezone component configured for that store (using '%z'), then runs that through the `json` filter to ensure that whatever the output will always be javascript-legal.

Now that you know your timezone offset, you can assemble your timer logic in Javascript using all your normal date/time tricks. For example:

```
var now = new Date();
var nowStr = now.toISOString();  // Output format: '2019-01-01T00:00'

// Chop off the time portion, then append your desired time & store timezone
var closingTimeStr = nowStr.split('T')[0] + 'T21:00' + timezone;

// We make a new date using today's date/time string
var closingTime = new Date(closingTimeStr);

// And now we can do math based on the difference
var difference_ms = closingTime - now;


if(difference_ms > 0){
  // Parse the difference into hours, minutes and seconds if a positive amount of time remains.  Writing a better parsing function is left as an exercise for the reader. 

  var hours = parseInt(difference_ms / (60 * 60 * 1000) );
  difference_ms %= (60 * 60 * 1000);

  var minutes = parseInt(difference_ms / (60 * 1000) );
  difference_ms %= (60 * 1000);

  var seconds = parseInt(difference_ms / (1000) );

  console.log('Hurry down! Closing in ' + hours + ' hours, ' + minutes + ' minutes, and ' + seconds + ' seconds!');
} else {
  // Show appropriate message if we're out-of-bounds
  console.log('Closed for today - try again tomorrow!');
}
```

Comment: You should probably use the `'now'` feature in the timezone. i.e: ```var timezone = {{ 'now' | date: '%z' | json }};```. Otherwise, you won't get accurate current timezone info with respect to daylight savings time.  Using `'now'` will give you the current time zone. For example, EST vs EDT (Eastern Standard Time vs Eastern Daylight Time).