# how to get actual universal time if i change the device time?

Tags: javascript, phonegap-plugins

**I want to show a current time whatever the system time is**.I am developing the hybrid mobile application in offline. I need a correct time of current if I changed the device time means it will show the current time only is there any possibility for that.In the new date is giving the what is the system date.If I change the system date javascript show that date only.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If no argument is provided in Date() constructor function, a JavaScript Date object is created according to the system time settings. The [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for Date object says:

> If no arguments are provided, the constructor creates a JavaScript Date object for the current date and time according to system settings.

**Syntax for getting JavaScript Date**

```
new Date();
new Date(value);
new Date(dateString);
new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

**You can follow this approach to show the correct time irrespective of the system time:**

1. When the app loads for the first time, make a call to your server to
   get current timestamp,
2. compare the server timestamp with the system
       timestamp, and store the difference in a variable (let's call it
       offset).
3. Write a custom function which returns the correct time by
       adding/subtracting the offset from the system time.

Comment: This approach won't be useful. First, the `date` object already contains the offset from UTC, and second, the system time may be changed while being offline.

Comment: i need a offline mode.no server interaction.Is it possible or not?.To getting the exact time

Comment: This is an interesting problem @KalaiPrakash. I'm digging more into it.

Comment: Android mobile have the setting option use network provider time for automatic like that anything will be there in javascript or plugins in phonegap?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `new Date().getTime();`

For more information [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047616/get-a-utc-timestamp-in-javascript/15012173#15012173)

Comment: no i need current time.you way is showing the system time. example if i change the system time 2:00 means it will returns 2;00 only.but what actually i  need is current time that means 2:37 ist