# How to convert Date().getTime() to UTC

Tags: javascript

I currently have this code below in javascript but it is currently at it's default timezone which is PST but I want it to be UTC by default or a way to convert it to UTC.

What are some ways around it?

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert a JavaScript date to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a UTC timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047616/get-a-utc-timestamp)

Comment: Remember to read through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date because if you don't know how to do something, (re)familiarise yourself with which built-in functionality you have available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `var now = new Date().toISOString();`

```js
var now = new Date().toISOString();
console.log(now)
```