# Difference between new Date(...).getTime() and Date.UTC(...)

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain why this two commands returns different results:

```
> new Date(2019, 0, 1).getTime()
> 1546293600000

> Date.UTC(2019, 0, 1)
> 1546300800000
```

According to MDN documentation of getTime method:

> The getTime() method returns the number of milliseconds* since the Unix Epoch.
>
> getTime() always uses UTC for time representation. For example, a client browser in one timezone, getTime() will be the same as a client browser in any other timezone.

And Date.UTC method:

> The Date.UTC() method accepts parameters similar to the Date constructor, but treats them as UTC. It returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

They are should be the same?

I just doubt how can I calculate difference between year 1924 and today. Because if we just add one year (in milliseconds) to timestamp of year 1924 it will be completely messed up. There is example of behavior I can't understand at all:

```
> new Date( new Date(1924, 0, 1).getTime() + 366 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 )
> Wed Dec 31 1924 23:57:56 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
```

Comment: my suggestion would be don't scratch your head with a javascript date object and start using momentjs.

Comment: `new Date( Date.UTC(1924, 0, 1) + 366 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ).toUTCString()`

Answer (score 4):

`new Date(2019, 0, 1)` creates a Date object representing the start of January, 1, 2019 **in your locale specificed timezone**. When converted to UTC, it will be a different time than the start of Jan 1 in UTC.

Running your second snippet to add one year gives the correct result for me. What browser or context are you running in?

Comment: Node 12 and Chrome. Same results

Comment: strange, works correctly on my version of chrome. If you're using node, skip the craziness that is Date objects and use [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment)

Comment: Yeah, maybe, Just interested in what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I get it now about UTC.

Answer (score 2):

`new Date(2019, 0, 1)` makes an object from your timezone, whereas `Date.UTC(2019, 0, 1)` gives you the timestamp in UTC.

I am in CE(S)T, so there will be a difference of 1 hour, 3600000 milliseconds:

```js
const timeInCEST = new Date(2019, 0, 1).getTime();
// 1546297200000
const timeInUTC = Date.UTC(2019, 0, 1)
// 1546300800000
const differrenceBetweenMyTimeAndUTC = new Date(2019, 0, 1).getTime() - Date.UTC(2019, 0, 1) 
// (I'm ahead, so the difference will be negative)
// -3600000

console.log(timeInCEST, timeInUTC, differrenceBetweenMyTimeAndUTC);
```

Comment: Thanks! Make sense for me now