# Timestamp from the web browser?

Tags: javascript, html, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine a web user's time zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/how-can-i-determine-a-web-users-time-zone)
>   [How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)

I would like to get the timestamp from my user web browser.

Example:
If now a user comes to my website from USA and another comes from Spain, I would like to save the respective time and date that it is now in USA and Spain.

Comment: timestamp should be identical.... timezone is just an offset of that...

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/how-can-i-determine-a-web-users-time-zone

Answer (score 1):

Getting the time with JavaCcript returns the current user's machine time.

The following JavaScript code will return the number of **milliseconds** since midnight Jan 1, 1970.

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
```

Now just grab the `timestamp` variable and send it back to your webserver, if that's where you want to save this information. The easiest unobtrusive way I can think of to do this is by using ajax to POST the time information back to your server, for example (using jQuery):

```
$.post("saveusertime.php", { time: timestamp} );
```

**Sources**

JavaScript's Date Object: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

jQuery's post() function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Just use `new Date().toString()`;