# How to get difference between time stamps on client (js) and server (php)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to know how long it takes for my AJAX call to drop on server and get response. I made this script to test it but it gives me strange results.

This is my client-side

```
$('.go').click(function(){
   var dateStart = new Date().getTime();
   $.post("timestamp_get.php", {}, function(data){
      var dateEnd = new Date().getTime();
      alert(dateStart + '\n' + data + '\n' + dateEnd);
   });
});
```

This is my server-side (timestamp_get.php)

```
<?php
$var = microtime(true);
$var = str_replace('.', '', $var);
echo $var;
```

Response:

```
1331718943881 - Right after I click on button
1331718943889 - Right after I get response from server
13317187704121 - PHP Response
```

As you can see it differs very much, why it is that and how can I fix that.

And also, how can I output milliseconds instead of UNIX time stamp?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5971324/797194

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just trimmed the last number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare seconds, but you compare seconds with miliseconds

Replace this

```
$var = microtime(true);
$var = str_replace('.', '', $var);
echo $var;
```

with this

```
echo date('U');
```