# jQuery - Jon Leighton's .date_input() - how to get UNIX time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I use [Jon Leighton's .date_input() datepicker](http://jonathanleighton.com/projects/date-input/) to work with date. Besides the fact I store date in UNIX timestamp, I should show date in the page in standart '15 Jun 2012' format. I initialize date inputs with this code:

```
$("#my_specific_input").date_input();
```

When I select date, it stores 15 Jun 2012. I need to POST to backend UNIX timestamp, but

```
$("#my_specific_input").val()
```

contains only '15 Jun 2012'. How do you think, is there are any other variants for sending timestamp to backend besides writing my own parser for '15 Jun 2012'-format ?

Thanks

p.s. yeah, I know that this plugin is no longer maintained and standart jQueryUI datepicker is way-more flexible, however I'm forced to use exactly this this one, don't ask my why :(

Comment: are you able to edit the backend? if its based on php its just one line of code

Comment: actually, I use NodeJS, however I think algorithm will be rather similar. You think, it would be better to process data as-is and parse it on backend, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

[How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)

```
Math.round(new Date($("#my_specific_input").val()).getTime() / 1000)
```