# compare system time with user time in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time

```
if (userDate.getHours() >= sysDate.getHours()) {
     alert('continue');
} else {
     alert('time is up');
}
```

I need to compare the system time with user entered time.By the above method i am able to compare the hours but i also need to compare minutes.pls suggest a suitable method for this

Comment: what do you mean with "user entered time" ? Is there a field where the user can enter time?

Comment: yes the time picked by user it is in 24hr format something like 10:00:00.Also i am picking a date from jsp page and concatenated the date and time using javascript.

Comment: Comparing minutes? Is that the desired granularity of the comparison? What about dates? If userDate has a value of 01.01.2013 00:01, and sysDate is 02.01.2013 23:59, your comparison would still succeed even though the time would be up by two minutes...

Comment: no only if dates are equal,i need to compare the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both `userDate` and `sysDate` are `Date` object, you can use `getTime()` method, like the following:

```
if (userDate.getTime() >= sysDate.getTime()) {
     alert('continue');
} else {
     alert('time is up');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown here: [How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)

you can use `Date.getTime()` to get milleseconds since Epoch. Then use simple integer math to compare:

```
if (userDate.getTime() >= sysDate.getTime()) {
     alert('continue');
} else {
     alert('time is up');
}
```

Comment: could you pls site an example for comparing