# Javascript timed loop with php

Tags: php, javascript, loops, time

I'm trying to display the current timestamp and refresh every second, doing this with php is too slow and has to reload the page and I know javascript doesn't, I just don't know how to, any help?

```
<?php
    $time = time() + 3600 * 15;
    echo $time;
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.5;time.php" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But you aren't displaying the current timestamp... you are displaying a timestamp 15 hours in to the future.

Comment: Because I live in Australia not the server location.

Comment: javascript will base it off the client's machine, but look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript) for how to get a timestamp in JS, and look [here](http://www.elated.com/articles/creating-a-javascript-clock/) for how to update a div with the time. (you don't need to worry about the bulk of the script in the second link, just how to update a div value and using `setInterval`

Comment: Yea I'd suggest as Jon said to use jQuery and setInterval, its really the only good way to do dynamic client side events. Php is oriented at server side processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript can call up a timestamp based on your local time. Use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) to loop and update the timestamp given by [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now).

```
setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("timestamp").innerHTML = Date.now();
}, 16);
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yx5CT/).