# JS countdown doesn't work

Tags: javascript

This code is supposed to show a seconds countdown on an HTML page.
But it does not work at all.
What could be wrong?
I kinda copied the code from a website, and just added few details.

```
function timer() {

    var now = new Date().getFullYear;
    var newdate = new Date("March, 19, 2014");

    var SecCount = (newdate - now) / 1000;
    SecCount = Math.round(SecCount);
    if (SecCount === 1) {document.getElementById("days").innerHTML= "يوم واحد"; }
    else if (SecCount === 2) {document.getElementById("days").innerHTML= "يومان"; }
    else if (SecCount > 2 && SecCount < 10) {document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = (SecCount + " أيام"); }
    else {document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = (SecCount + " يوم"); }

    setTimeout(timer,1000);
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` should be out of the function I believe.

Comment: `Date().getFullYear` is the function literal. you need parenthesis to call the function thus `Date().getFullYear()`

Comment: Are you calling `timer` anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you want the full date that is now for the variable 'now', you should use [`Date.now`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript). getFullYear will only return 2014 which will give you unexpected results. 
**this solution is only if you want a count down till March 19 2014.**

```
// var now = new Date().getFullYear
var now = Date.now();
```

the variable day count isn't in the form of days, it should be this instead

```
// convert the seconds into days
var DayCount = Math.round(SecCount / (3600 * 24));
```

did you call the function to start the timeout loop ?

```
timer();
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L9a7q/1/)

Comment: Thanks Jay! How can I make it calculate hours too? I mean 03/19/2014 10:00:00 for example.

Comment: And how to set timezone.

Comment: if you can't explicitly put that I  the date function then just add 10 hours to ie `3600 * 10`

Answer (score 0):

Do you call timer() function from somewhere in your code besides setTimeout.  You need to call it to start executing and call setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a litte [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F5hgP/2/) which does the job.

to get the time left over the `%` operator is very useful!

Comment: I was trying to do it to be like this website: http://ss-cal.com, will yours still work?