# calculate difference between two timestamp and get difference in unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datepicker

I want to calculate the difference between two dateTime, one date is submitted by user and other is current time:

```
user submitted time - now = difference in unix
```

user submitted time format is:

```
2014-03-26 10:52:00
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do this with [`getTime()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/221297/1671639) which returns the number of milliseconds.

```
var ds = "2014-03-26 10:52:00"; 
var newDate = new Date(ds).getTime(); //convert string date to Date object
var currentDate = new Date().getTime();
var diff = currentDate-newDate;
console.log(diff);
```

Sometimes there are chance for *cross browser compatibility in parsing the date string* so it is better to parse it like

```
var ds = "2014-03-26 10:52:00";
var dateArray = ds.split(" ");  // split the date and time 
var ds1 = dateArray[0].split("-"); // split each parts in date
var ds2 = dateArray[1].split(":"); // split each parts in time
var newDate = new Date(ds1[0], (+ds1[1] - 1), ds1[2], ds2[0], ds2[1], ds2[2]).getTime(); //parse it
var currentDate = new Date().getTime();
var diff = currentDate - newDate;
console.log(diff); //timestamp difference
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I am looking for. I will try and let you know.

Comment: This is not working, both give NaN. This is my date: `2014-03-26 12:50`

Comment: @user007 missing to add seconds.  Then change this line `var newDate = new Date(ds1[0], (+ds1[1] - 1), ds1[2], ds2[0], ds2[1]).getTime();`

Comment: I already tried with, `2014-03-26 13:37:54` and this out NaN too

Comment: @user007 hmm okay lets check it out http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/LVmyj/1/ try with different values and let me know which one fails

Comment: oh its working now, it was due to negative result. cuz user input time is for future. Thanks and your solution is perfect.

Comment: do i need to divide diff/1000 ? I think current time is in milliseconds

Comment: @user007 it depends, some use unix timestamp with 13 digit; other 10 digit which called as [Unix epoach timestamp](http://www.epochconverter.com/)

Comment: I need epoch, for sending it to server. So I think you said I need o divide. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) library

```
 var user_submited_time = moment('2014-03-26 10:52:00');
 var now = moment();
 var value = user_submited_time - now;
```