# How to convert dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss to epoch time in Javascript without regex?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a date like this :

```
var intervalStart="13-11-2014 16:22:00"
```

and an epoch time like this :

```
1415876254
```

I need to convert the string date into epoch to compare the two! Am kind of lost here. I looked at the other answers and by using :

```
var formattedDays = intervalStart.split(" ")[0].split("-");
var epoch = new Date(formattedDays[2], formattedDays[1] - 1, formattedDays[0]).getSeconds;
```

I tried something like this too :

```
var formattedDays = intervalStart.split(" ")[0].split("-");
var formattedTime = intervalStart.split(" ")[1].split(":");
var epochStart = new Date(formattedDays[2], formattedDays[1] - 1,formattedDays[0],formattedTime[0],formattedTime[1],formattedTime[2],0).getTime()/1000;
```

^ But this seems to be giving numbers like 16 etc!!

I can get the seconds for upto days("13-11-2014") correctly but how do i include time("16:22:00") here?Thanks a lot in advance!

P.S : I do not want to use some external library . And I would prefer no regex !

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify the goal. So now answers from @Talha and myself are obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close, *getSeconds* is a method, not a property so:

```
var formattedDays = intervalStart.split(" ")[0].split("-");
var epoch = new Date(formattedDays[2], formattedDays[1] - 1, formattedDays[0]).getSeconds();
```

note the `()` after *getSeconds*. But *seconds* returns just the seconds part of the date, not seconds since epoch. For that you need `...getTime() / 1000` since *getTime* returns milliseconds since epoch.

You can do it more simply using:

```
var b = intervalStart.split(/\D+/);
var epoch = new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0], b[3], b[4], b[5]) / 1000;
```

you can even do:

```
var after = new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0], b[3], b[4], b[5]) / 1000 > 1415876254; // false
```

or

```
var after = new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0], b[3], b[4], b[5]) > (1415876254 * 1000);
```

You're right to manually parse the string. Giving that format string to the Date constructor will not necessarily be consistently parsed by all browsers, and it will not be parsed at all by some.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want the Epoch time in *seconds* and not in *milliseconds*. So just divide by 1000:

```
var epoch = Math.floor(new Date(...).getTime() / 1000);
```

What you did to get the `Date` object is correct.

Comment: @Juhana, because the title of the question is confusing us!

Comment: FYI I don't have enough reputation to downvote an answer

Answer (score -1):

You can use this  code :

```
<script>
    var d = new Date();//date you want to convert to timestamp
    alert(d.getTime());//this is how you can convert any date to timestamp
 </script>
```

in your case you can simple write:

```
<script>
var formattedDays = intervalStart.split(" ")[0].split("-");
var epoch = new Date(formattedDays[2], formattedDays[1] - 1, formattedDays[0]).getSeconds;
var timestamp = intervalStart.getTime();
</script>
```

for more info, please check this question.
[How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)

Comment: You missed the point. I want to include the "time" part in the date object . i know i can use .getTime() !!!

Comment: And, in addition, because he says "I need to convert the string date into epoch to compare the two"

Comment: use this, i have also checked this.
var d = new Date(); d.setFullYear(2014, 11, 13); // your date 
var n = d.getTime();