# How to get current date extended in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get current date with format like this:

Thursday, APR. 9, 2015

How can I do this?

Comment: check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) for date with formats

Comment: come on...this is not difficult at all to figure out in a google search. you are expected to at least have done basic research before posting questions here

Comment: Try [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). you can format as you want.

Comment: Use [these JavaScript methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)

Comment: sorry @charlietfl, I made some google search, but couldn't find exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 ways of instantiating a Date object in java script:

new Date()
new Date(milliseconds)
new Date(dateString)
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)

*Using new Date(), creates a new date object with the current date and time

I think that the last one is probably the one that you would be wanting to use. There is a lot of documentation that you could have searched to help find this, specifically "W3schools". That is a great beginner (and even not beginner) go to site for things like this. Check out [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) Information about the date class that you need.

I hope this helps!