# How to get timestamps of starting and finishing video capture with Cordova?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins, cordova-4

I use the Cordova [Capture plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html) to record videos in an Android application. How can I get timestamps of the recording was started and finished (preferably with milliseconds)?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the example prvoided at [Cordova Capture](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureVideo_full_example),

Try adding in codes for [getting timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript) when capture is called and at captureSuccess callback?

```
// Called when capture operation is finished
//
function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
    var timeFinished = new Date().getTime();
    var i, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
    }
}

//...(omitted)

// A button will call this function
//
function captureVideo() {
    // Launch device video recording application,
    // allowing user to capture up to 2 video clips
    var timeStarted = new Date().getTime();
    navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 2});
}
```

Of course, you should define them at the correct scope so that you can use them elsewhere.