# how to get user local machine time zone in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, timezone

how to get user local machine time zone in c#. I'm trying to get time by using

```
var PublishedOn = DateTime.Now;
```

but time shows according to the server not local user machine.

Comment: DateTime.Now represents the current time zone of the machine. UtcNow is neutral. Are you in a web environment and want to get the TimeZone of the client request... or what is the question?

Comment: Is this code running in a Windows program? In an ASP.NET program? `DateTime.Now` does just give the time according to the machine running that code.

Comment: Use a geolocation service or JavaScript

Comment: i'm trying to develop mvc application for web environment.

Comment: Why did you accept an answer that doesn't work!

Answer (score -5, accepted):

`TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone` is used for the time zone on the computer where the code is executing. Check these links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.currenttimezone.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.local.aspx

Comment: How is this the correct answer? this will still give the server Timezone *not* the local pcs

Comment: Not only that, but `TimeZone` should not be used at all anymore.  It was replaced by `TimeZoneInfo` a long time ago.  MSDN is clear on that.  Still, it won't help for the requested function, as it requires JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

The only place where you can get such information reliably is the client machine. [Javascript would be the way to go.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/221294/993547)

Geo-location will not work when behind a proxy and is generally not very reliable (in my experience).

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.Now` will be the machine where the code is executed. You can use the IP of the incoming request:

```
Request.UserHostAddress
```

to get some idea of the geo location using an API like

> https://freegeoip.net