# How can I get timeStamp in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, timestamp, document-ready

I want when page loaded get timeStamp but I can't.

This is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id = "x">time</p>
        <script src="jquery/jquery1.12.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(event){
               $("#x").text(event.timeStamp);
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object to do this work. `now()` method return timestamp in miliseconds. Of course javascript return timestamp with client time.

```js
$(document).ready(function(event){
    var timeStamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    $("div").text(timeStamp);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will not get event object in ready call. As a workaround you can use `$.now()` for instance:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#x").text($.now());
});
```

Comment: It return timestamp in milisecond.

Comment: @ Mohammad ,what is $ in $.now()

Comment: @ehsan `$.now()` is method of jquery that return value of `(new Date).getTime()`. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.now/

Comment: @Mohammad, timestamp is in miliseconds or seconds?

Comment: @ehsan timestamp is in second but javascript return it in milisecond.

Comment: @ehsan See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript