# Retrieve UTC timestamp with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an app where I don't care about time zones and need only UTC time. This means my timestamps need to match UTC time.

My goal is to get 2 UTC timestamps for current day. Let's say UTC time is **June 21st 13:04:47**.

For this time I would like to get timestamp for midnight of that day **June 21st 00:00:00** and timestamp for 24 hours later **June 22nd 00:00:00**. Timestamps for those two times are **1466467200000** and **1466553600000**.

This is how I am currently doing it:

```
    var today = new Date();
    var todayStart = new Date(Date.UTC(today.getUTCFullYear(), today.getUTCMonth(), today.getUTCDate(), 0, 0, 0));
    var todayEnd = new Date();
    todayEnd.setTime(todayStart.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

    console.log("start of the day: " + todayStart.getTime())
    console.log("end of the day: " + todayEnd.getTime());
```

This returns correct results but I am wondering is this reliable and is it the right way to accomplish what I want. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried Moment.js? It is a lifesaver when it comes to dealing with dates in JS: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Not really a duplicate, that one is about actually getting a timestamp at all. This code already demonstrates a knowledge of `getTime`. This question is asking how to manipulate the `Date` object to get a timestamp for a specific time of day.

Comment: The answers of that question answer this question. Still needs 4 others to agree with me anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing it works and should be reliable. If I had written it I would have done it a little differently.

```
var start = new Date(),
  end;

// set midnight today
start.setUTCHours(0);
start.setUTCMinutes(0);
start.setUTCSeconds(0);
start.setUTCMilliseconds(0);

// set to midnight tomorrow
end = new Date(start);
end.setUTCDate(start.getUTCDate() + 1);

console.log("start of the day: " + start.getTime());
console.log("end of the day: " + end.getTime());
```

This code creates the start date as the current date/time and then zeros out the time portions. Then getting 24 hours later is just a matter of creating a duplicate `Date` and incrementing the date by 1. It does require a little more code but it makes it explicit what you are doing and will probably be easier to read and comprehend when maintaining the code in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly discourage use of native Date object for this.

Check out `moment` and `moment-timezone` - they cover all your use cases out of the box: http://momentjs.com/

With that you can do: `moment().tz('Europe/Berlin').utc()`