# local time to utc/unix (timezone aware) using Intl (ecma 402)

Tags: javascript

Though support may be limited, is there a way to parse a datetime string to utc/unix  (locale & time zone aware) in new Intl (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402) spec, something similar using moment

http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/, http://momentjs.com/docs/

```
var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
var unix = newYork.valueOf();
```

note: I haven't tried above, but reading the API, I think this may be a way.

Edit:
the question was a specific instance of internationalization as I wanted to parse user input in a locale aware manner. Example, numbers (1,000 and 1.000 may be equal depending on locale). same way user may enter time as `lundi 27 juin 2016 10:15` in dt picker/text field, which needed to be parsed.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: actually, the question was a specific instance of internationalization as I wanted to parse user input in a locale aware manner. Example, numbers (1,000 and 1.000 may be equal depending on locale). same way user may enter time as `lundi 27 juin 2016 10:15` in dt picker/text field, which needed to be parsed.