# Disable boostrap datepicker day after 10am

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, disabled-input

Could not find this online anywhere, hope you guys can help.

I have a bootstrap datepicker in my webpage (so not jQuery, it's not working for some reason). This datepicker is part of an order form. People are supposed to place an order **before** 10am, so they can pick it up later that day at 11.45am (or order for a few days later).

**The client wants to disable the user from picking the current day WHEN it is past 10am.**

So lets say you order on 1sept and it is 9am, you can select the day of pickup to be 1 september. But when you order on the 1sept and it is already past 10 am, you can only pick 2september for pickup (or 3 sept or 4 or 5 ....)

How do I set this? I have already found to disable sundays, but not this...

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://boutique.dev/order" accept-charset="UTF-8">  

<!-- ... -->

  <input id="datepicker" type="text" class="form-control" name="date">

<!-- ... -->          

</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yy",
        daysOfWeekDisabled: "0"
    });

});
```

Comment: For one, I'd use startDate, not daysOfWeekDisabled. Second, should it take the customers time into account or the store owners? Third, a conditional statement might work, load one instance when it's before 10 AM, and one after.

Comment: Ah great, I did not look at startDate! Should work perfectly when manually setting it depending on the time, smart thinking, will try. Also, why not use `daysOfWeekDisabled ` when there should never be orders on a Sunday. Lastly everything is local (only 1 timezone).

Comment: I didn't realize they didn't accept orders on Sunday; in that case you shouldn't change that. Now if you need something for the time, just check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript