# Create timestamp in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, date, timestamp

I am trying to do this:

```
string thisReturn = "";

DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
now = new DateTime (now.Year, 1, 1);
int yearDay = (int)(now.Subtract (new DateTime (1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
thisReturn = yearDay + "000";
```

Which will return this: **1451606400000**

---

EDIT

I have now done this:

```
var unix = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);
var timestamp = unix+"000";
```

This will return this: **1480661530000**

Almost there, but how do I set it to the 1st of january current year?

---

Now, how do I do exactly the same in javascript?

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)

Comment: you can do `var time = new Date().getTime();`

Comment: in JavaScript Date.prototype.getTime() returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970

Comment: OK, I almost got it (read edited) but i need it to set the timestamp for the beginning of the year. How do I do that?

Comment: Mansa the answer you selected is not correct. I strongly encourage you to look at the output it produces since it isn't in UTC and therefore isn't compatible with your C# code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do the same in javascript

```
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
```

Ofcause you can add some parameters for `new Date()`

Comment: I almost got it, but need the date to be the first day of this year (see my edited post)

Comment: so you can use this: `new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)` of cause with less parameters if there is no special time needed.

Comment: Seriously? This answer isn't even correct. NO you can't use less parameters because the first parameter is the year.

Comment: @RalphRitoch you can just use `new Date(year, month, day)` there is no time needed. time will be 0:00:00 o´clock then

Comment: LenglBoy, try it yourself... (new Date(2016,0,1)).getTime() it doesn't return the UTC for january 1st.

Comment: If this solution was correct it would return 1451606400000 which it doesn't (Unless you live in GMT+0)

Answer (score 1):

The following will get you the timestamp for the beginning of the year.

```
thisReturn = (function(d) { 
    d.setUTCMilliseconds(0);
    d.setUTCSeconds(0);
    d.setUTCMinutes(0);
    d.setUTCHours(0);
    d.setUTCMonth(0);
    d.setUTCDate(1); 
  return + d; })(new Date());
```

Comment: That's a very longwinded way of doing `Date.UTC(2016,0,1)`. If a UNIX time value is required, then `Date.UTC(2016,0,1)/1000`.

Comment: RobG, there's no need for the /1000 if you note their code they add the zero's at the end. Either way, you still need to grab the current UTC year for your code to work. This longwinded method only requires the creation and destruction of one date object so it should be more efficient.

Comment: At least you could do `d.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0); d.setUTCMonth(0,1)` to remove 4 function calls. I don't think calls to *new Date* are that expensive.

Comment: Robg don't forget every object you create also needs to be destructed. Regardless I profiled it and using Date.UTC with a second date object on Firefox is about 3X faster than the method I came up with. Regardless this was about being correct I wasn't presenting this as the most optimized solution. My solution was the only correct solution (yours would be also if you submitted it). I coded yours as thisReturn = (function(d) { 
    var d2 = Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(),0,1);    
  return + d2; 
  };)(new Date());

Comment: Cool, was just suggesting something more concise but stopping short of obfuscation. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To get the timestamp in seconds, you can use:

```
Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
```

Or alternatively you could use:

```
Date.now() / 1000 | 0
```

Please let me know if its worked for you.

Thanks!