# how to get formatted date time like 21032018041217PM using javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

When I am using new Date, I am getting something like as follows:

```
Wed Mar 21 2018 16:14:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

but what I want is `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`/(`21032018041217PM`) formatted time string

Here(`21032018041217PM`) is 21 is `date, 03-month, 2018-year, 04-time, 12-minutes, 17-seconds` and It should be `AM/PM`.

Comment: You want like this --21032018041217PM

Comment: Try to read this: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp)

Comment: @Mr.Pandya, Yes i want like that

Comment: @Mahendra You need to write custom function to format date like that. Date Object dont have property to convert directly to ur requirmenr

Comment: @Mr.Pandya, i tride like this but i'm getting like this 2132018163431 formate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var date = new Date();
var dateFormat =  (date.getDate().toString().length == 1? "0":'' ) + date.getDate() + (date.getMonth().toString().length == 1? "0":'' ) + date.getMonth() + "" + date.getFullYear()
var hours = ((date.getHours()%12).toString().length == 1?'0':'') + "" + (date.getHours()%12);
var minuts = ((date.getMinutes()).toString().length == 1?'0':'') + "" + (date.getMinutes());
var seconds = ((date.getSeconds()).toString().length == 1?'0':'') + "" + (date.getSeconds());
var format = (date.getHours() >= 12 && date.getHours()%12 != 0) ? 'PM':'AM'
var yourDate = dateFormat + hours + minuts + seconds + format
```

Comment: '21032018041217PM' using this how to add 30min exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to achieve your desired format:

```js
console.log( moment().format('DDMMYYYYhhmmssA') )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: here what is moment(), how to define?

Comment: It's time manipulations library. I have posted a link above. You can either download `moment.js` script file and include it in your project or add it via `npm` if possible.

Comment: @JeremyThille Thanks, I'm new to this snippeting stuff. Perfaps I should examine it a bit soon :)

Comment: @Jeremy, Here if i use this moment.min.js '<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>' and if i run its getting error 'Refused to load the script 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".'

Comment: @Mahendra then just download the library and include the local version.

Comment: @Vladyslav, https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/locale/az.js. Is this fine?

Comment: @Mahendra In case you need locale-specific version, just download it, put along with your sources and include it using `<script>` tag.

Comment: No, az.js is the Azerbaidjan locale (plug-in). Just include moment.min.js

Comment: @Vladyslav, can i get the link of moment.min.js library

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this quite easily by using `momentjs` library. The documentation is quite detailed here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

It will allow you to handle date formatting any way you desire.

You can download it from here: https://momentjs.com/

**Without using `momentJS` library:**

To convert the current date and time to a UNIX timestamp do the following:

```
var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
```

> getTime() returns milliseconds from the UNIX epoch, so divide it by 1000 to get the seconds representation. It is rounded using Math.round() to make it a whole number. The "ts" variable now has the UNIX timestamp for the current date and time relevent to the user's web browser.

You can also take a look here: [How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)

Comment: Your solution without `Moment.js` is wrong. You will receive simple timestamp (total number of seconds elapsed since 01/01/1970). It's not what the author is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moment.js otherwise you can do string concatenations and calculations be careful month is 0-11 which means 3 might actually be 04 not 03.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using like this,

```
date.getDate()+""+(date.getMonth() + 1)+""+date.getFullYear()+""+ date.getHours()+""+date.getMinutes() +""+date.getSeconds();
```

but this formate of the result `2132018163431` i'm getting

Comment: You just need to pad the numbers. `function pad(num,length) {return (new Array(length).join("0") + num).slice(-length);}` and then you can do `pad(date.getDate(),2) + pad(date.getMonth()+1,2) + pad(date.getFullYear(),4) + pad(date.getHours(),2) + pad(date.getMinutes(),2) + pad(date.getSeconds(),2);`

Comment: Don't forget about ante/post meridiem (AM/PM)