# Google Sheets printing out date in milliseconds? Using google scripts (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am using google sheets with google scripts to sort some data and then put it into a new sheet. I have been using the `.valueOf()` method to grab the data from an array that grabbed all the data using `sheet.getDataRange().getValues();` and has worked perfectly with grabbing everything in all the other places besides my column containing the dates in the `"dd/mm/yyyy"` order. It grabs it but then puts it into my new sheet in the form of some massive number (which I think could possibly be seconds or milliseconds). I don’t want a time stamp, I want to reverse whatever that time stamp thingy is.

Example: [Original Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRnUq.png) and [After grabbing date and moving to new sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPkD2.png)

Below I have posted the code I am using. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Code: https://pastebin.com/snn3jDcH

```
line where I grab the date:


for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    test = data[i][2].valueOf().substring(0,5);
    if(test === "ES014")
    {
       DateStore[count] = data[i][0].valueOf();
       NameStore[count] = data[i][1].valueOf();
       NumStore[count] = data[i][2].valueOf();
       QuantityStore[count] = data[i][3].valueOf();
       count++;
    }
```

Sorry about the formatting, but it wouldn't let me post unless I did it this way. No clue why but sorry! Thank you for this long read!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)

Comment: I think, this is not duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `sheet.getDataRange().getValues();` and then doing `valueOf()`

Simply only do `sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();` and I think valueOf() is not necessary.

For further informations check this out

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues

Comment: Thank you, I’ll be sure to test this!