# How To Create a Timestamp In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I need to create a Timestamp like below. I have tried lots of ways , but couldn't get this format.

How can I create a current time and date in this Timestamp format in JavaScript ??

> 2018-08-20T04:19:50.670Z

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
console.log(new Date().toISOString());
```

Comment: Don't even need the `toISOString()`.

Comment: @jhpratt Without toISOString() whatever format we expect, that won't come.

Comment: Have you tried it? I did and you get the expected format.

Comment: @jhpratt for console.log(new Date()); Output : Mon Aug 20 2018 11:47:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

console.log(new Date().toISOString()); Output : 2018-08-20T06:17:29.129Z

Comment: @saravananmp - When I console.log(new Date().toISOString()); this , I got the Output : 2018-08-20T06:17:29.129Z. But , when I did like this - var timestampama = new Date().toISOString();
console.log("Timestamp - " +timestampama); , it always gives me only 6. How can I Fix this ??

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Timestamp like `2018-08-20T04:19:50.670Z` using

```
console.log(new Date().toISOString());
```

Or,

```
console.log(new Date());
```

But note that in **chrome**

```
console.log(new Date().toISOString());
```

will return timestamp in this format:

```
`2018-08-20T06:19:24.386Z`
```

but

```
console.log(new Date());
```

will return timestamp in this format: `Mon Aug 20 2018 11:50:23 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

But in **Mozilla**, both yeilds same result.

If you use `.toISOString()` with `new Date()`, then it will return a `string` of the timestamp, otherwise it will return a `Date` object. This is the only difference in using `.toISOString()`. So, its depends on you what do you want???

Comment: Interesting that Chrome does that, because when I tried it in Node (which also uses V8), it did the same as Firefox.

Comment: @jhpratt, does `console.log(new Date().toISOString());` and `console.log(new Date());` give the same result in `node`.

Comment: Yes, at least in node 8.11.2

Comment: @jhpratt, yes, in node both yeilds same format of timestamp.

Comment: I checked in `Node 8.11.4`

Comment: I was more intrigued as to _why_ there's a difference, when both Chrome and Node use V8.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178322/discussion-between-inullpointer-and-jhpratt).

Comment: @iNullPointer - When I console.log(new Date().toISOString()); this , I got the Output : 2018-08-20T06:17:29.129Z. But , when I did like this - var timestampama = new Date().toISOString(); console.log("Timestamp - " +timestampama); , it always gives me only 6. How can I Fix this ??