# Is Perl DateTime epoch in milliseconds or seconds?

Tags: javascript, perl, datetime

I need to compare the timestamp given by my backend (which is in Perl) and the timestamp of by front-end (which is in JS), so I need to be sure that they both use the same time unit.

For JS it's easy, [quoting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime):

> A number representing the **milliseconds** elapsed between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the given date.

For Perl, the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#$dt-%3Eepoch()) about `$dt->epoch()` says:

> Return the UTC epoch value for the datetime object. Datetimes before the start of the epoch will be returned as a negative number.
>
> The return value from this method is always an integer.
>
> Since the epoch does not account for leap seconds, the epoch time for 1972-12-31T23:59:60 (UTC) is exactly the same as that for 1973-01-01T00:00:00.

To me, it's not clear if the returned integer is in milliseconds or seconds (in the second case I would need [to convert JS epoch in seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5971324/4480180) or viceversa).

Which one is correct?

Comment: Can't you just make the same date in both languages and compare the timestamps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the context of DateTime, "epoch" refers to [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which is the number of seconds that aren't leap seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

```
$ perl -MDateTime -e'CORE::say DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => 1 )'
1970-01-01T00:00:01

$ perl -MDateTime -e'CORE::say DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => 1000 )'
1970-01-01T00:16:40
```

However, DateTime supports times with a resolution of nanosecond, so you could use the following to get a JavaScript timestamp.

```perl
my $js_time = $dt->epoch * 1000 + $dt->millisecond;
```

---

Of course, getting a value other than zero for the millisecond component assumes the DateTime object was created with a sufficiently precise time. That's not the case for

```perl
my $dt = DateTime->now();
```

because it uses `time` operator to obtain the current time. To get a higher-resolution timestamp, you could use the following:

```perl
use Time::HiRes qw( time );

my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => time() );
```

Comment: How can I convert a higher-resolution DateTime to epoch with nanoseconds?

Comment: @Ωmega, Those are available as `$dt->epoch` (as shown) and `$dt->nanosecond` (unsurprisingly)

Comment: I missed that. Thanks

Comment: So if you mean the same format as Time::HiRes::time, it's `$dt->epoch + $dt->nanosecond / 1_000_000_000`

Answer (score 6):

```
$ perl -MDateTime -wE 'say DateTime->new( year => 1971 )->epoch'
31536000
$ bc <<< 365*24*60*60
31536000
```

Comment: So, what's the solution?