# ng-zorro datepicker got one day less

Tags: javascript, ng-zorro-antd

I use ng-zorro-antd's datepicker in my project,

https://ng.ant.design/components/date-picker/en

When I choose the date and time, 
console will show correct time with timezone like

`Mon Jun 01 2020 05:10:30 GMT+0800 (中國標準時間) {}`

But when I submit to backend,the datetime will become

`2020-05-31T21:10:30.942Z`

It's one day less,
How can I resolve this?

I make a example like below
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-acsrm4-gmdget

Open F12 first, Then choose one day and click send, 
You will see the situation in the network parameter.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's NOT one day less. It's UTC time. 國際標準時間  0500 -8 (the +8 offset) = 2100 which is the time displayed.

Comment: But If I save this time to database, It's hard to query the correct time.

Comment: So leave it in UTC, then display the locale version of the time.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString

Comment: You have to make a choice: either ONLY deal in local time (and if someone throws something in a different timezone and your program goes crazy)  or you convert ALL the date and time to UTC internally and only display local time based on locale settings.  I recommend the latter, probably with help of moment.js or similar library.

Comment: Just to clarify: it's still the same TIME, just displayed differently. As long as you STORED these same value (the actual date-time, not the string version), they will query the same.

Comment: May I ask how to leave UTC date? The ng-zorro dependency on date-fns, I don't know how to set global date format.

Comment: Did you read through https://ng.ant.design/docs/i18n/en specifically "how to format a date using date-fns"?

Comment: Yes, I already read and try this, but this just for setting languages, didn't resolve my problem.

Comment: I think I need to know how to setting a global date format to my project, thank you for your patient, I try hard to solve this, If I find a way, I will share here. thanks anyway.

Comment: So your point is "It's hard to query the correct time in database"? Usually the frontend and backend transfer Unix timestamp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript

Comment: why not the date pick just show the actual UTC date on the calendar?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of moment-timezone.js (front-end or back-end)

1. get local time zone on client: `moment.tz(moment.tz.guess())`
2. define moment date object: `moment(yourDate.toISOString())`
3. find the local time zone off set: `moment.tz(moment.tz.guess()).utcOffset()`
4. off set the date object with local time zone off set: `moment(yourDate.toISOString()).utcOffset(moment.tz(moment.tz.guess()).utcOffset())`
5. format the result ISO: `format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS')+'Z'`

Single Line:
`yourDate = moment(yourDate.toISOString()).utcOffset(moment.tz(moment.tz.guess()).utcOffset()).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS')+'Z';`