# Convert New Date() to timestamp in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a problem converting `new Date()` to timestamp in ES6.
Timestamp should look like this `10012020120012`.

10/01/2020 12:00:12AM should be
10012020120012

here is my code below:

```
let myDate = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit',
    year: 'numeric',
  });
 myDate = myDate.split('-');
 let newDate = new Date(myDate[2], myDate[1] - 1, myDate[0]);

console.log(newDate.getTime())
```

Comment: Are you trying to get [`MMddYYYYHHmm`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date) or a [Unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)?

Comment: @VLAZ. `10/01/2020 12:00:12AM` should be `10012020120012`

Comment: Then why create the date, then make it into another date object to get the Unix timestamp of it? Check the first link for how to format dates. For convenience you can also use a date library like date-fns, for example.

Comment: @VLAZ. ok date-fns is fine. How would i convert that to timestamp using date-fns

Comment: `dateFns.format(new Date('2020-10-01'), 'MMDDYYYYHHmm');`

Comment: Could you please check my answer again

Comment: @VLAZ. Thanks but could you do it without package?

Comment: @Joseph again - check the first link in my first comment.

Comment: @VLAZ. I can;t see anything related to what i want, `10012020120012`. Could you put the code here? Thank you

Comment: @Joseph [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30272803/) - you can just use `getMonth()`, `getDate()`, `getYear()`, `getHours()`, `getMinutes()`, `getSeconds()`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it works in my console. Split by '/' instead of '-'

```js
let myDate = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit',
  year: 'numeric',
});
myDate = myDate.split('/');
let newDate = new Date(myDate[2], myDate[1] - 1, myDate[0]);

console.log(newDate.getTime())
```

Comment: For Example: `10/01/2020 12:00:12AM` should be `10012020120012`

Comment: Do you want to create from datetime string?

Comment: Convert `new Date()`  to something like `10012020120012`

Comment: Sorry I didnt downvote you. why is 1578....? Today is Oct