# Mongo: Getting current time in milliseconds since 1970

Tags: mongodb

In Mongodb I have a field representing a timestamp (milliseconds since 1970), but it is in fact a long saved from Python.

I now want to get all entries done after a certain time. I cannot find a way though how to get the current time as a timestamp in a mongo shell style.
One thing I've tried e.g. was:

```
use binfut;
db.getCollection("liq").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : { 
                "coin" : "BTC-USDT", 
                "side" : "SELL", 
                "timestamp" : { 
                    "$lte" : ISODate("2018-10-02T01:11:18.965+0000")
                }
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```

But I also used new Date(), etc.

Is there a way to get this done?

Comment: Maybe `{$expr: {$lte:[{$toDate: "$timestamp"}, ISODate("2018-10-02T01:11:18.965+0000")]}}`

Comment: Perhaps `timestamp: {$gte: (new ISODate("2018-10-02T01:11:18.965+0000")).valueOf()}`

Answer (score 0):

See [How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript).

```
> +ISODate("2018-10-02T01:11:18.965+0000")
1538442678965
```

Comment: It's not about javascript, but mongo shell ;)

Comment: What language do you think the shell uses?