# Convert between date formats in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was given `data.json` file with the dates in the following format:

```
"creationTime": 1542111235544,  
"creationTime": 1545880457898,
```

Which translated to:

```
13/11/2018, 13:13:55
27/12/2018, 04:14:17
```

by doing:

```
new Date(ticket.creationTime).toLocaleString()
```

How can I do the backward operation? For example, if I have a date as:

```
27/09/2014
```

How can I get the code like in the others?
The time is optional (I can add 00:00 am if needed)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: No. I don't even see my format mentioned

Comment: 1. Few answers show that one 2. even the ones that don't show how to handle the data. You need to separate it into parts and give it to the `Date` constructor.

Comment: I need to do the backward operation. They're all talking about how to convert dates etc. I need the json code (don't even know the name of it), that I mentioned above

Comment: That is not what I need. I need the number, the code, such as: 1542111235544. Example: convert from 13/11/2018, 13:13:55 to 1542111235544

Comment: [How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/221294)

Comment: I appreciate the help, but the question asks about how to get a current timestamp, the current time. Doesn't deal with conversions.

Comment: You can convert the from the format yourself using the first link, then get the timestamp using the second link. There is no built-in functionality for that.

Comment: Have you tried https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/ library for your needs. I don't know if the above format matches but you can explore

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to convert a string back to milliseconds, which would be something like this: `new Date('12/27/2018, 04:14:17').getTime()`?

Comment: @user1791914 this may not produce the correct results since it's not a standard date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using this code:
Noted date format used here mm/dd/yyyy

```js
  var dateToNumber=new Date("09/27/2014").getTime(); //input month/date/year
console.log("dateToNumber",dateToNumber);

  var numberToDate=new Date(1411754400000).toLocaleString();
console.log("numberToDate",numberToDate);
```

Comment: This is not culture agnostic. Bad general solution.

Comment: `"09/27/2014"` is not a standard date format, so the interpretation of it would be implementation dependant.

Comment: @zhulien,  the comments he already mentioned about the back process he wants to generate number format from the date-time. I am not thinking about the date format. Just implement the flow of the process.

Comment: @VLAZ just implement the process of back to generate the number from the date.

Comment: @PalashKantiBachar Like I said, it is a pretty bad solution and you actually demonstrated exactly that. As you see, his date is `27/09/2014` and yours - `new Date("09/27/2014")`. Yes, it is the same date but in different format. Culture format should be taken into consideration and ignoring it like that is a pretty bad sign.