# jQuery.Load() not working right in IE9

Tags: jquery, data-binding, asp.net-3.5, internet-explorer-9, jquery-load

On the home page of my site, `jquery.load()` is ran at `$(document).ready()`, and requests a URL something like:

"/ajax/Listings.aspx?pageindex=0"

When this page is ran, in the `Page_Load()` a `ListView` is bound to a `DataSet` which returns some products to appear. If there are no items, then the `EmptyDataTemplate` displays something like:

"There are currently no products"

In my system, there is 1 product that should be displayed. In FireFox, this is returned and displayed on the page correctly.

However, in Internet Explorer the `EmptyDataTemplate` is displayed. Furthermore, if the URL ("/ajax/Listings.aspx?pageindex=0") is opened up in the IE9 browser (as a fresh tab), then this returns 1 product.

Why does IE9 not bind any items to the `ListView` when `jQuery.Load()` is used?

Comment: Show more details.  We need the full code of the call so we can see the bug.  My guess is you don't have the right parameters to the Load function.

Comment: The parameters must be right or else it wouldnt work in FireFox or IE9 as a fresh tab. Regardless, I believe I have found the solution and have posted it below. Only just got IE9 and I already hate it lol

Comment: Ultimately what did you change to get it to work?  You changed the parameters.  I found your scoffing at my *correct* comment to be annoying.

Comment: I may have misterpreted what you were saying then perhaps. I was under the impression you were implying the parameters would need to be different so that it would return a different value. The correct value was being returned, just it was being cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While appending random strings to the URL works, the best approach to handle this is to disable the cache:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168963/stop-jquery-load-response-from-being-cached)

Comment: +1 Thats much neater than adding cache busters for every request, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after posting this I went back to try and see if I can work it out myself, and believe I've found the solution!

Because I'd opened the ajax page in a seperate tab, when I went back to the home page, this was now being shown.

Therefore, I believe this is cached, and the only way to refresh the cache is to open it in a new tab.

So, I've added a random string to the end of the URL to ensure it doesn't cache the page each time:

```
function random_string() { return String((new Date()).getTime()).replace(/\D/gi, '') }

var url = "/ajax/Listings.aspx?pageindex=0&rnd=" + random_string
```