# Clear IE cache when using AJAX without a cache busting querystring, but using http response header

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, caching, http-headers, browser-cache

I'm having the classic IE-caches-everything-in-Ajax issue. I have a bit of data that refreshes every minute.

Having researched the forums the solutions boil down to these options (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997857/grails-best-way-to-send-cache-headers-with-every-ajax-call):

- add a cache-busting token to the query string (like ?time=[timestamp])
- send a HTTP response header that specifically forbids IE to cache the request
- use an ajax POST instead of a GET

Unfortunately the obvious querysting or "cache: false" setting will not work for me as the updated data file is hosted on Akamai Netstorage and cannot accept querystrings. I don't want to use POST either.

**What I want to do is try send an HTTP response header that specifically forbids IE to cache the request** or if anyone else knows another cache busting solution??

Does anyone know how this might be done? Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
(function ($) {
var timer = 0;
var Browser = {
    Version: function () {
        var version = 999;
        if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) version = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")[1]);
        return version;
    }
}
$.fn.serviceboard = function (options) {
    var settings = { "refresh": 60};

    return this.each(function () {
        if (options) $.extend(settings, options);
        var obj = $(this);
        GetLatesData(obj, settings.refresh);
        if (settings.refresh > 9 && Browser.Version() > 6) {
            timer = setInterval(function () { GetLatestData(obj, settings.refresh) }, settings.refresh * 1000);
        }
    });
};
function GetLatestData(obj, refresh) {
    var _url = "/path/updated-data.htm";
    $.ajax({
        url: _url,
        dataType: "html",
        complete: function () {},
        success: function (data) {  
            obj.empty().append(data);               
            }
        }
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a random number to the GET request so that IE will not identify it as "the same" in its cache. This number could be a timestamp:

```
new Date().getTime()
```

**EDIT** perhaps make the requested url:

```
var _url = "/path/updated-data.htm?" + new Date().getTime()
```

This shouldn't cause any errors I believe.

**EDIT2** Sorry I just read your post a bit better and saw that this is not an option for you.

You say "is hosted on Akamai and cannot accept querystrings" but why not?
I've never heard of a page that won't accept an additional: "?blabla", even when it's html.

Comment: What I should have mentioned is that the data file is hosted on Akamai Netstorage which does not allow querystrings. 
Unfortunately is you pass a querystring in Akamai, it pulls from the Origin server and we want to avoid having a heavy traffic load on Origin.

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me crazy. I tried many cache busting techniques and setting cache headers. So many of these either did not work or were wild goose chases. The only solution I found which tested to work correctly was setting:

```
Header Pragma: no-cache
```

I hope it saves others with IE headaches.