# jQuery update php array into javascript

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

Simplified version of my problem:

Here is  javascript example called **example.html** writes the content of a javascript array.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
// javascript array called data
data=[
      [1,2],[3,4],[5,6]
     ]
function WriteText(){
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++) document.write(data[i],"<br> ")
}
WriteText();
</script>

</head>
</html>
```

Instead of array the values are written  columns  **file.txt** located  in  the same server directory where the **example.html** is. **file.txt** looks like that

```
 1 2 
 3 4 
 5 6
```

I would  like to accomplish the same functionality as the example above by  reading this file with php and pass it to the javascript.
**file.txt** is a log file where new values are being appended every few seconds 
So when new values are added I want to see the   changes updated to screen. 
Here is  **getfile.php** function that reads the file.

```
<?php
    $values = array();
    foreach(file("file.txt") as $line => $content) {
    $values[$line] = explode(' ',$content);
    }
    echo json_encode($values)
?>
```

And here is the code that does this.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function WriteText(InputData){
    for(var i=0;i<InputData.length;i++) document.write(InputData[i],"<br> ")
}
 //WriteText(data);

setInterval($.get("getfile.php", { "func": "doSomething" },WriteText  , "json"),1000);

</script>

</head>
</html>
```

I got this idea from
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

This code displays the **file.txt**. However when I manually append new values to the **file.txt**  there is no update in the browser. If I refresh the page manually  the new values are shown as well.
So what am I doing wrong??
Is it the php script or probably  I am not using the `setInterval()` properly.
 Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'd recommend looping onSuccess instead of blind polling, the issue is that you haven't created a proper closure for setInterval:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.get('getFile.php',{},WriteText,'json');
},1000);
```

Comment: Thank you. That function(){} worked. What do you mean by looping on success?Is it the same success they're talking about in here? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/I am still very new  to the whole javascript php thing.

Comment: Honest mistake.  3 other answers and they all missed this.  : )

As far as looping, you can either setInterval, which will fire your request off blindly... or you can just iterate on success (and/or failure).  this way, if an http request takes a while for some reason, you don't wind up calling the function too often.  Instead of setInterval, just use a single setTimeout, and chain that in WriteText.

Comment: How about if I want to pass the file to be read as a variable in the php funciton.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Expire header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) in PHP to tell your browser that the page expires immediately (by passing a date in the past). If you don't, the browser will cache the page.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into the php header(). I've just started learning php.

Answer (score 1):

once the php script finishes looping it stops reading the file.

it doesn't even output anything until php has stopped looking at the file.

the javascript gets no further info from the php script.

to do this you need to use ajax to periodically make a new request for more data and display the new data.

additionally you will need to modify the php to output only the changes, possibly by adding a datetime line

Comment: Actually the first column of my file.txt is the POSIX time. So I guess I could easily modify my php script to update only the changes and in the WriteText() javascript function I could do something like `data.push([NewData])` to append the new data entries to the already displayed aray.

Answer (score 0):

Do this at the beginning to avoid cache.

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```

Linked - [Stop jQuery .load response from being cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168963/stop-jquery-load-response-from-being-cached)