# How to change request to avoid cached results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lighttpd

I get xml file from server with function ( JQuery )

```
function load_config_xml(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'config/conf.xml',
        dataType: "xml",
        success:parse_xml,
        error: function(){
            alert("Error during loading xml file");
        }
    });
}
```

but it doesn't return fresh results, lighttpd caches. How to change request to avoid cached results ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop jQuery .load response from being cached](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168963/stop-jquery-load-response-from-being-cached)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest workaround is to explicitly use a `POST` request. A browser will not cache those:

```
function load_config_xml(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'config/conf.xml',
        dataType: "xml",
        type: 'POST',     // here we go
        success:parse_xml,
        error: function(){
            alert("Error during loading xml file");
        }
    });
}
```

jQuery also offers the option `cache` which you can set to `false`. That creates the some outcome:

```
cache: false
```

Basically jQuery will just modify the query string for each request, which of course you could do on your own aswell:

```
url: 'config/conf.xml?cachebuster=' + (+new Date())
```

Comment: maybe close as loads of dups!