# $(this) doesn't work in a function

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, this

The following code loads html content from a file (i used [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168963/stop-jquery-load-response-from-being-cached))

```
<script>
$.fn.loadWithoutCache = function (){
 $.ajax({
     url: arguments[0],
     cache: false,
     dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
        $(this).html(data);        // This is not working
      //$('#result').html(data);   //THIS WORKS!!!
        alert(data);           // This alerts the contents of page.html
    }
 });
}


$('#result').loadWithoutCache('page.html');

</script>
```

Please let me know what the problem is?
I hope it's something stupid :)

Edit: CORRECT CODE

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$.fn.loadWithoutCache = function (){
 var $el = $(this);
 $.ajax({
     url: arguments[0],
     cache: false,
     dataType: "html",
     context: this,
     success: function(data) {
     $el.html(data);
    }
 });
}

$('#result').loadWithoutCache('page.html');

});
</scipt>
```

Thanks Jon and everyone!

Comment: Inside a jQuery AJAX call, `this` refers to the jQuery XHR object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback (`success`) function runs when the response arrives, and it doesn't run in the scope of the `loadWithoutCache` method, as that has already ended.

You can use the `context` property in the `ajax` call to set the context of the callback functions:

```
$.fn.loadWithoutCache = function (){
  $.ajax({
    url: arguments[0],
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
    context: this,
    success: function(data) {
      $(this).html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you saying the `.ajax()` call is not within closure of `loadWithoutCache()`? O.o

Comment: @Guffa: If yes, then please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qcVqj/). Or did I misunderstood you?

Comment: @Tadeck: The context is not part of the closure, it's determined by how the function is called.

Comment: @Guffa: You were referring to **scope** within your answer (" _... it doesn't run in the scope of the loadWithoutCache method, as that has already ended_ "), and it remains in the same scope, has the same variables accessible as it would be executed within `loadWithoutCache` function (excluding `this` / context). See [closure definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)).

Comment: @Tadeck: The code can access variables from the closure, but it doesn't run in the scope of the function where the closure was created. The reason that closure is called closure and not scope is that it's not the same as scope.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that inside the success callback, `this` does not have the value you expect it to.

However, you do have access to `this` (with the expected value) inside `loadWithoutCache` itself. So you can achieve your goal by saving `$(this)` into a local variable and accessing it from inside the success handler (creating a closure).

This is what you need to do:

```
$.fn.loadWithoutCache = function (){
 var $el = $(this);
 $.ajax({
     url: arguments[0],
     cache: false,
     dataType: "html",
     success: function(data) {
        $el.html(data);
        alert(data);
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: No, you don't *need* to do that, there are other ways.

Comment: I would say it is correct, except you should not write `$el = $(this);` - it should be `var $el = $(this);`. What do you think?

Comment: @Tadeck: True, thanks for the catch. I did write "local variable" but that slipped through.

Comment: @Jon: No problem, upvoting now ;)

Comment: @miro: Are you sure your jQuery selector is correct? `[]` is what happens when you have a selector that doesn't match anything...

Comment: the problem was that i needed $(document).ready(function() { //// });
Thank you guys!!!

Answer (score 2):

You scoping of `this` is incorrect. You need to save your `this` to a variable outside of the ajax success function and reference it from that variable

```
<script>
$.fn.loadWithoutCache = function (){
 var self = this;
 $.ajax({
     url: arguments[0],
     cache: false,
     dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
        self.html(data);        // This is not working
      //$('#result').html(data);   //THIS WORKS!!!
        alert(data);           // This alerts the contents of page.html
    }
 });
}


$('#result').loadWithoutCache('page.html');
```

Answer (score 2):

Within the AJAX callback, `this` is bound to a different object.  If you want to reuse the target of your plugin, store (capture) it in a local variable and use that.

```
$.fn.loadWithoutCache = function (){
 var $target = $(this);
 $.ajax({
     url: arguments[0],
     cache: false,
     dataType: "html",
     success: function(data) {
        $target.html(data); // note change
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: +1 This is almost the same as Jon's answer, except yours is correct (although the difference may not be visible for everyone and someone may not care about global variables).

Answer (score 1):

JQuery's this is contextual. http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/

`console.log($(this))` at different points to see what it refers to.

Comment: I get nothing... no matter where i put it it results in []