# In Jquery combining $.get with $(this).remove() breaks $(this)

Tags: jquery

I want to delete some data displayed in a HTML table row (first on the database and then remove from the HTML table). I have added a delete link to each HTML table row, and when this link is clicked, I want first to make a jQuery **$.get** to update the database, and if that returns successful, then I want to remove the HTML row. I have gotten each part working successfully separately, but when I try to *combine* them, I run into trouble. When combined, the part that makes the AJAX call to update the database works, but not the part that does the **$(this).remove()**. I can see that, at the moment of calling $(this).remove(), the value of $(this) is referring to the $.get, when I know I need it to be referring to ".delete_link". But I don't see how I can change that. Clearly I'm struggling with some of the fundamentals of jQuery. I tried breaking each part up into component functions, but that seemed to make things even worse.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delete_link").click(function () {
      if (confirm('Are you sure???')) {
        $.get("/comments/ajax-delete-comment?comment_id=4220537", function(response) {
            if (response == 1) {
              alert("Couldn't update database");
            } else {
              $(this).closest('tr').fadeTo(400, 0, function () {
                $(this).remove();
              });
            }
        });


        return false;
      }
      return false;
    });
  });
```

Comment: Aside: You may want to use the `data` option/parameter with `$.get` instead of using a query string in the URL.

Comment: Inside the callback, `this` is different to what it is outside.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [$(this) doesn't work in a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859558/this-doesnt-work-in-a-function) - This question has been asked over a zillion times.

Comment: Set `var cLink = $(this);` before the `$.get()` call, and use `cLink.closest(...)` and `cLink.remove();` inside the callback.

Comment: @RobW believe me, I searched. Knowing the right keywords is part of the solution. I'm not one to idly ask questions or waste people's time.

Comment: @EvanMulawski - thanks for that, much appreciated. Any other general tips would be greatly appreciated too! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply capture `this` in a variable.

```
if (confirm('Are you sure???')) {
    var that = $(this);
    $.get("/comments/ajax-delete-comment?comment_id=4220537", function(response) {
        if (response == 1) {
            alert("Couldn't update database");
        } else {
            that.closest('tr').fadeTo(400, 0, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }
    });


    return false;
}​
```

Comment: Thanks. I notice you have kept the $(this).remove() - why is that?

Comment: You're welcome! Doesn't really make a difference, but for me it helps to remind me about the scope of the callback to `fadeTo` in this instance.

Comment: Right, I'm kind of confused though. Has $(this) somehow gotten reassigned the right value?

Comment: Yes! :) Once you call `fadeTo`, `this` inside its callback automatically refers to the element that your chain is operating on; the default behavior for jQuery chains.

Comment: Oh man, that is confusing. Any links to articles/explanations? I'm accepting your answer, by the way.

Comment: Once you get it, it will become easy and a great way to program. But yes, it was initially confusing to learn. I can't think of any articles, but I was looking on Amazon and this looks like a helpful book: http://www.amazon.com/jQuery-Cookbook-Solutions-Examples-Developers/dp/0596159773/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1332444668&sr=8-1 , specifically chapter 5.

Comment: Actually, check out this article: http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated. I still can't get over that my question was answered in 1 minute, when I spent all evening trying to figure it out! Hahaha!

Comment: Don't feel bad! It's a common problem that we see here frequently (hence why it was answered by four people in 1 minute) :). Consider it a logical pitfall to make for anyone learning jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You should store $(this) in a variable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delete_link").click(function () {
      if (confirm('Are you sure???')) {

        var $link = $(this);

        $.get("/comments/ajax-delete-comment?comment_id=4220537", function(response) {
            // THIS in this context is jQuery not the link you want

            if (response == 1) {
              alert("Couldn't update database");
            } else {
              $link.closest('tr').fadeTo(400, 0, function () {
                $link.remove();
              });
            }
        });


        return false;
      }
      return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You should really do `var $link = $(this)`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Initially I thought your answer was the same as SimpleCoder's but I see that you have a $ in front of the variable, where he/she has just a "that". Are they both correct solutions?

Comment: yes, the $ is just a programmer convention. It makes it easier to see that the variable is jQuery object. Javascript does´nt care what you name your variables.

Answer (score 2):

try caching `this` on click

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delete_link").click(function () {
      var $this=$(this);
      if (confirm('Are you sure???')) {
        $.get("/comments/ajax-delete-comment?comment_id=4220537", function(response) {
            if (response == 1) {
              alert("Couldn't update database");
            } else {
              $this.closest('tr').fadeTo(400, 0, function () {
                $this.remove();
              });
            }
        });


        return false;
      }
      return false;
    });
  });
```

Comment: You should really do `var $this = $(this);`

Comment: Thanks for this. Initially I thought your answer was the same as SimpleCoder's but I see that you have a $ in front of the variable, where he/she has just a "that". Are they both correct solutions?

Comment: @BrianFenton yes both were the same solutions `var $this` and `var that` are the same things

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delete_link").click(function () {
      var delIndex = $(this).index();

      if (confirm('Are you sure???')) {
        $.get("/comments/ajax-delete-comment?comment_id=4220537", function(response) {
            if (response == 1) {
              alert("Couldn't update database");
            } else {
              $('.delete_link').eq(delIndex).closest('tr').fadeTo(400, 0, function () {
                $('.delete_link').eq(delIndex).remove();
              });
            }
        });


        return false;
      }
      return false;
    });
  });
```

Comment: It would be faster to save `this` in a var, than to have to look up `$('.delete_link')` in the DOM again.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I think the other answers are more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `$.get` callback, `this` is no longer your element.

You need to save `this` as a variable before `$.get`.

```
var that = this;
$.get(url, function(){
    $(that).closest('tr') // 'that' will be the correct element
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do you suggest I save "this" and not $(this) as others suggest? Is there an advantage in that?

Comment: @BrianFenton: I save `this` just in case I need to something with the element without jQuery.

Comment: +1 thanks for the reply. So you can still access the jQuery $(this) later on, even if you only save "this". Interesting.

Comment: @BrianFenton: Yep, you can do `$(that)` later, or you can do `that.id` if you want to.