# jQuery - 'this' selector doesn't work inside callback function

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$(this) doesn't work in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859558/this-doesnt-work-in-a-function)

I'm writing post removing code in jQuery, The removing itself is made via post-request to backeds, after server returns 200, I want to delete this post on client-side.

```
$('.delete-post').click(function() {
    $.post($(this).attr('href'), {}, function(data) {
        $(this).closest('.post').remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

However, I've noticed that inside function(data) {...) selector 'this' doesn't work. I need to remove closest to `$('.delete-post')` div with class '.post'. How to manage this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$(this)` exists in the `click event` but `function(data) {` is not part of click event `rather callback function`. So save the $(this) in some variable for instance `that` for later use.

Try this:

```
$('.delete-post').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var that = $(this);
    $.post(that.attr('href'), { }, function(data) {
        // $(this).closest('.post').remove();
        that.closest('.post').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: You should explain why `this` has a different value in the callback.

Comment: I have already explained thanks for reminding me @jfriend00

Comment: Thank you very much, now I've got it! Simple and clear)