# How to achieve a 302 redirect after AJAX post? Trying to implement prg-pattern

Tags: php, jquery, redirect, seo

I am trying to implement a "post request get" pattern for SEO reasons like explained in this example:
https://www.advertising.de/seo/wiki/prg-pattern.html

My implementation consits of a pseudo link element, styled via CSS like a link:

```
<span data-prg="redirect_url.html" class="btn redir-link" title="test">PRG Link test</span>
```

A jquery AJAX POST call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var request;
    $(function() {
        $('.redir-link[data-prg]').click(function (e) {
            var $self = $(this);
            request = $.ajax({
                url: "/prg.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    url: $self.data("prg")
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Th PHP file that will create the redirect URL and which should 302 redirect via GET

```
header("Location:".$_POST['url'], true, 302);
exit;
```

The apache log states that the implementation works:

"POST /prg.php HTTP/1.1" 302 
"GET /redirect_url.html HTTP/1.1" 200

However the page inside the browser does not change. I suspect that the php file that is called via ajax will change but this is not what I want. The orginial page should be redirected.

How could I accieve a 302 redirect for the original page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access property with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376016/how-to-access-property-with-jquery)

Comment: The original page won't be redirected because you're not loading a "page", you're loading *data* via ajax.  Ajax, by definition, does not affect the whole page.  It may be that the data returned is html, but it's not a browser load-302-redirect.  
The PRG pattern is "post-redirect-get" (not -request- as in the question).  If you want the entire page to change, you'll need to add a `location.href=` in success/done.  One way to handle this is to return a response object that includes the new url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect in a ajaxed page the page isn't available for the user,do a simple form that will trigger a post request to `/prg.php` in prg you then redirect back