# ajax working in chrome not firefox

Tags: ajax, firefox, google-chrome

Hy ,

I have this ajax code that works fine in Chrome but in Firefox does not.
   I have a php script that generates a captcha code image , i verify it through javascript and ajax.
   If the user inserts the correct code in firefox the scripts returns 1 , if the user insert the wrong code the script returns 0 and changes the picture , if the user inserts again the wrong code the script returns 0 but it does not change the picture (In firefox , in chrome works fine everytime)

```
 $("#finish").click(function() {
            //$(function() {
                    var text = $("#captchaText").val();
                    //alert(text);
                    //var session = $("#captchaText2").val();
                    //alert(session);
                    $.ajax({
                          //type: 'POST',
                          url: 'includes/scripts/validation.php',
                          data: 'id='+text,

                          success: function(response){
                            alert(response);
                            if(response == 0){
                                    $('#poza').html('<p><img src="includes/scripts/CaptchaSecurityImages.php" /></p>')  ;
                            }
                          }

                        });


        });
```

Comment: May be firefox is caching data.

try adding a random no in your url.

like includes/scripts/validation.php?rand=29994
or CaptchaSecurityImages.php?rand=234324

Comment: it worked i missed a " but now it works , thank you very much

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop jQuery .load response from being cached](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168963/stop-jquery-load-response-from-being-cached)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that firefox stores it in cache. 
By adding a rand solved it.