# jQuery cross domain request still failing in IE, but using jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, cross-domain

My Ajax cross domain request is failing in IE 9 with "Access denied". I have read through several posts regarding this topic, and AFAIK it should work.

1. IE9 and jQuery 1.8.1
2. Call is `async`, `jsonp` and `crossdomain`, `cache` is `false`. These are the prerequisites I have found.
3. Works in latest Firefox and Chrome.
4. `jQuery.support.cors` is true
5. Even the response header is set: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485347/jquery-cross-domain-request-response-headers))
6. The returned JSON code would also be correct, have used a checker (also see 3.)

So why is this failing with **Access denied**? Any idea? Could it be because my code is called from within a "JavaScript" library, and not a `<script></script>` tag on the page?

What am I missing?

```
    // The code is part of an object's method (prototype)
    // code resides in a library "Mylib.js"

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        crossdomain: true, // typo, crossDomain, see my answer below
        datatype: "jsonp", // dataType
        success: function (data, status) {
            if (status == "success" && !Object.isNullOrUndefined(data)) {  ... }

        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           // access denied
        }
    });
```

-- Edit -- based on Robotsushi's comments, some further research ---

1. Indeed, cannot find `XDomainRequest` in the jQuery source code (1.8.1)
2. If I do not set cors (`jQuery.support.cors = true`) I'll end up with a "No Transport" exception.
3. Still wondering why others obviously succeed with IE9 cross domain requests, e.g. here: [jQuery Cross-Domain Ajax JSONP Calls Failing Randomly For Unknown Reasons In Some IE Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170718/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-calls-failing-randomly-for-unknown-reasons-in-som?rq=1)
4. The way jQuery handles this, seems to be around the code below, but this is not called in my particular case, no idea why?

   // Bind script tag hack transport
   jQuery.ajaxTransport( "script", function(s) {

   ```
   // This transport only deals with cross domain requests
   if ( s.crossDomain ) {
   ```
5. A similar situation here in year 2010: [Jquery $.ajax fails in IE on cross domain calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362474/jquery-ajax-fails-in-ie-on-cross-domain-calls?rq=1) However, this should have been solved by the later jQuery versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, working now. Couple of mistakes on my side:

1. It is `crossDomain: true, dataType: "jsonp"` , typo - missed capital letters.
2. JSONP requests are **not** transparent. The data are not simply JSON notation, but have to be wrapped in a Js function call (on the server side): see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP Basically this means, if you cannot modify the sent data, JSONP is not the right option for you.

All things considered, it works. So my personal checklist would be:

1. Use `json` if possible (e.g. with Chrome, FF, or most likely IE10). Make sure response header is set: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`
2. If using `jsonp`, check: `async: true`, `jsonp` and `crossdomain: true`, `cache` is `false`, `jQuery.support.cors` is `true` These are the prerequisites I have found.
3. Also make sure the `jsonp` response is a function call ([JSON wrapped in function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)), **not** "just ordinary" JSON data.

Comment: Using Jquery 1.10 I didn't need the cors = true set for this to work ... apparently it's better now. Kudos though, it took me 4 hours to find this post (which actually had the fix in it).

Comment: you also don't need `crossDomain:`, access control headers, `async:`, `cache:`, or `jQuery.support.cors`.

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar issue trying to access some json that I'm storing on Google Cloud Storage and accessing using jQuery's ajaxing. This worked fine in Chrome and Firefox, but I was getting 'access denied' messages when testing in IE (9 and below).

The way I got around it was to use jsonP, explicitly:

1. re-write my json file to be a javascript file with a javascript variable to hold the json data, e.g.

`(function (o) {
          variableName = [json]; 
     }(window.[nameSpace] = window.[nameSpace]|| {}));`

1. include the url to the javascript file within the  tag of the html file, e.g.

   `<script type="application/javascript" src="[url to javascript file]"></script>`
2. Consume the data via it's variableName

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

IE requires you to use `XDomainRequest` instead of XHR for cross site.

You can check out the easyXDM which is a js library that abstracts this process for you.

Alternatively see this :

[Access denied to jQuery script on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087549/access-denied-to-jquery-script-on-ie)

Comment: Isn't that what jQuery should do as well? Abstract it and use XDomainRequest.

Comment: Good hint, but still wondering how others succeed with their x-doamin requests in IE9: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170718/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-calls-failing-randomly-for-unknown-reasons-in-som?rq=1