# Get contents of UL from another file with jquery

Tags: jquery

have a jquery slider (FlexSlider) set up on a website. The slider displays content from an unordered list.  It would be a lot more convenient for me if instead of listing the images names on the same page as the slider is located, I could import ul class "slides" from another file via jquery. Can anyone tell me what command I could use in my main slider file to import the ul from another file?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

To load HTML from another file on your domain into your site you can use jQuery's [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

```
$('#elementOnYourSite').load('path/to/file.html');
```

You can even load a specific element from the other file into an element on your site:

```
$('#elementOnYourSite').load('path/to/anotherFile.html #elementInOtherFile');
```

Comment: For future searchers, when implementing this solution, I found that the content was cached, which wasn't ideal for me.  The solution for that issue was here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2158535/1063287