# Partial View not being fully re-rendered after Ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view that I need to fully refresh after an Ajax call. When I do, part of it is but not all of it. When I step through it to see what is being caught it looks like just the forms in the partial view are being refreshed and not other parts of it. Is there anything that could be causing this?

jQuery and Ajax that refreshes the view and view that contains other partial views:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ChangeHeatName').click(function (e) {
        var tdata = $('#form1').serialize();
        var origname = $('#HeatNameDiv').find('input[name="heatName"]').first().val();
        var newname = $('#HeatNameDiv').find('input[name="updatedHeat"]').first().val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                mCollection: tdata,
                heatName: origname,
                updatedHeat: newname
            },
            url: '@Url.Action("ChangeHeatName","Home")',
            //url: "/Home/ChangeHeatName",
            success: function (result) { success(result); }
        });
    });


    function success(result) {

        $('#HeatNameDiv').dialog('close');
        //Ajax with problem
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("ButtonsPartial","Home")',
            success: function (result2) { $("#ButtonsPartial").html(result2); }
        });
        $("#Partial_Chem_Analysis").html(result);
    }
});
</script>

<section>
<div id ="ButtonsPartial" title="ButtonsPartial">
    @Html.Action("ButtonsPartial", "Home")
</div>
<div id="Partial_Chem_Analysis" title="Partial_Chem_Analysis">
    @Html.Action("PartialChemAnalysis", "Home", Model)
</div>
</section>
<section>
```

The partial view:

```
@using System.Data;
@using System.Dynamic;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Linq;
@model TheManhattanProject.Models.ButtonsModel


<div id="Chem_Buttons">
<h2 class="alignleft">Chemistry Table</h2>
<p class="alignright">Heat Name<input type="text" name="heat_name" value="@Model.heatName" class="search-query" placeholder="Search" style ="width:100px" readonly="true"/>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="Change_Heat_Name" value="Change_Heat_Name" name="action:Change_Heat_Name" type="button"> Change Heat Name</button>
Grade<input type="text" name="heat_grade" value="@Model.grade" class="search-query" placeholder="Search" style="width:100px" readonly="true"/>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="ChangeHeatGrade" value="ChangeHeatGrade" name="action:Change_Grade" type="button">Change Grade</button>
Delete Record<input type="text" name="delete_record" value="@Model.heatName" class="search-query" placeholder="Search" style ="width:100px" readonly="true"/>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="DeleteRecord" value="DeleteRecord" name="action:Delete_Record" type="button">Delete Record</button>
  </p>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  </div>
<div id="HeatNameDiv" title="Change Heat Name">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeHeatName", "Home", "POST"))
   {
    <section>
        Heat Name:<input type="text" name="heatName" value="@Model.heatName" style ="width:100px" readonly="true"/>
        //Value staying to what was entered not ""
        Change to:<input type="text" name="updatedHeat" value="" style="width: 100px" />
        <input type="button" id="ChangeHeatName" name="ChangeHeatName" value="Change" />
    </section>
}
</div>

<div id="HeatGradeDiv" title="Change Heat Grade">
@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeGrade", "Home", "POST"))
{
    <section>
        Heat Grade:<input type="text" name="grade" value="@Model.grade" style ="width:100px" readonly="true"/>
        Change to:<input type="text" name="updatedGrade" value="" style="width: 100px" />
        <input type ="hidden" name="hiddenHeat" value ="@Model.heatName)" />
        <input type="button" id="ChangeGrade" name="ChangeGrade" value="Change" />
    </section>
}
</div>

<div id="DeleteRecordDiv" title="Delete Record">
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteRecord", "Home", "POST"))
{
<section>
    Heat Name:<input type="text" name="heatName" value="@Model.heatName" style ="width:100px" readonly="true"/>
    <input type="button" id="DeleteRecordBtn" name="DeleteRecordBtn" value="Delete" />
</section>
}
</div>
```

Comment: I see two AJAX calls. Which one is giving you problems?

Comment: Sorry, should have specified. It's the second one. I'll add a marker in my code.

Comment: Found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528196/caching-issue-with-loading-partial-views-into-jquery-dialogs

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand after your edits is the response from this bit of code is giving you problems.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '@Url.Action("ButtonsPartial","Home")',
    success: function (result2) { $("#ButtonsPartial").html(result2); }
});
```

A couple of things with this is

1. You don't show a container with `ButtonsPartial` id. So if it doesn't exist it you can't display the result.
2. It is using GET and that can be cached by your browser. With the browser debugger like firebug or developer tools you can see the response to the ajax call and see if it really is getting new data from your server.

**Edit:** I see your `ButtonsPartial` div now. So #1 isn't an issue.

Comment: I've checked what it's getting back as a response and it's exactly what is in the partial view. The main issue that I can see is that what's in the "Change To:" field does not get reset. However when I look at the response it is set to "" like it should, it's just not reflecting that on the page. If that makes any sense.

Comment: When I look at the response in firebug, it's the HTML of the ButtonsPartial view as it should be rendered.

Comment: If you comment out `$("#Partial_Chem_Analysis").html(result);` does the `ButtonsPartial` load as you expect?

Comment: If I do that it has the same results

Answer (score 0):

You have no Partial_Chem_Analysis tag

Comment: It's contained within another view that's not relevant to the question.

Comment: @Jasen that view refreshes fine and does what it's supposed to. I'll update my question with that code so you can see. Also, I've updated the question because I marked the part that was not updating incorrectly