# Flask url_for() no cache

Tags: python, caching, flask

I put some files in static directory and these files are keep updated by some back end processing. I used `url_for()` to return url to client side.

But I found that even if I removed the old files from static directory and regenerate the updated files, it still display the content of old files on the client browser. I think the old file has been cached.

Does anyone know how to set no-cache for the `url_for()` function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you positive? Press `CTRL-SHIFT-R` on your keyboard to forcibly reload the page.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I dont want to reload the whole page. I just used ajax to refresh parts (e.g., iframe) of the page

Comment: If you're using jQuery, disable caching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168963/stop-jquery-load-response-from-being-cached

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [blog post](http://www.subdimension.co.uk/2012/05/31/Flask_Response_headers_and_IEs_cache.html) about this a while ago.

Basically, you need to create a response to send, then set some extra headers on the response, then send the response:

```
def send_url(method):

    response = app.make_response(url_for(method))

    response.headers.add('Last-Modified', datetime.datetime.now())
    response.headers.add('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0')
    response.headers.add('Pragma', 'no-cache')

    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling all caching just because once in a while you have a new release is really not good practice.  Caching of css and js gives huge performance benefits.

What good sites do is to add a timestamp of the file to the resource URLs.  For example, in Flask, here is a way to do this transparently: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/40/