# FullCalendar is not showing events in IE/FF from JSON feed

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I have a valid JSON-Feed (validated with JSONLint) that works fine with Chrome. But there are no events showing up in IE/FF. I tried to use different time formats and everything else that was already answered in similar questions.

JSON Feed:

```
[{"id":"64","title":"","start":"1356517800","end":"1356521400","allDay":false}]
```

Calendar:

```
    $('.roomscal').fullCalendar({
events: 'http://..../events.php'
            });
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Any error? What says Firebug?

Comment: In Chrome Firebug shows a correct response. The same request is empty in Firebug when i try it in FF.

Comment: Antwort-Header
Date Fri, 28 Dec 2012 14:15:25 GMT
Server Apache
X-Powered-By PHP/5.3.18-nmm1
Cache-Control no-cache, must-revalidate
Expires Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Vary Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding gzip
Content-Length 94
Keep-Alive timeout=1, max=100
Connection Keep-Alive
Content-Type application/json

Comment: I tried this on my fullcalendar, and it worked fine (just hard-coded the output of my JSON feed to your output above) in both Chrome and Firefox. Shows up as an event at 6:30pm on December 26th for me.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check the caching?

```
$.ajaxSetup ({ 
  // Disable caching of AJAX responses 
  cache: false; 
});
```

To tell jQuery to not cache.

Code found here. [Stop jQuery .load response from being cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168963/stop-jquery-load-response-from-being-cached)