# How to use the Load method for an html element?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a drop down list as below which just shows a list of user names and their values:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedUser,
                                  Model.UsersSelectList,
                                  "-- Select One --",
                                  new { onChange = "users_onchange();" })
```

and the javascript is as below which would call an action when an item is changed:

```
    function users_onchange() {

        var selectedUserId = $('#SelectedUser').val();

        if (selectedUserId == "") {
            selectedUserId = 0;
        }

        $('#EmailAccountsContainer')
            .load('/MyEntityController/EmailAccounts', { userId: selectedUserId });
   }
```

and the EmailAccountsContainer is just a div:

```
<div id="EmailAccountsContainer"></div>
```

and the EmailAccounts Action accepts a userId and returns a partial view displaying another drop down list.

The problem is that the call to the Action only happens after the first change to the Users drop down list. If a second user is selected, no call is made to the Action.

I have turned down the caching as well on the controller:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public class MyEntityController : Controller
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Check with Firebug and see whether you can see the request

Answer (score 1):

Bind you onchange event using **[on Event](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** with Body tag

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('body').on('change', '#SelectedUser', function(){
  var selectedUserId =$(this).val();
   if (selectedUserId == "") {
        selectedUserId = 0;
    }
   $('#EmailAccountsContainer')
        .load('/MyEntityController/EmailAccounts', { userId: selectedUserId });
 });
});
```

Comment: that shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the response is cached in your browser.

See this for how to solve this with Jquery:

[Stop jQuery .load response from being cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168963/stop-jquery-load-response-from-being-cached)