# Random string being added onto JS var

Tags: javascript, jquery

basically I am trying to load some PHP into a DIV using JS.
Using this code:

```
$('#preview').load("includes/event_image_crop.php?img=" + fname);
```

However, its not just putting the fname string in there its adding a random string too like this `&_=1369168657782`

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I skimmed a little bit of the code of first - thats my mistake on this post.

Comment: And you should `... + encodeUriComponent(fname)` in case the filename has characters invalid in the url like an ampersand

Comment: Does `event_image_crop.php` redirect the user somewhere?

Comment: jQuery automatically adds that to make sure the request isn't cached

Comment: @FritsvanCampen No - it uses the variable to grab an image

Comment: It's possibly jQuery's anti-caching mechanism

Comment: If you don't want jQuery to do this, use `$.ajax()` and set `cache: true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a feature designed to prevent caching. It should have no effect on the page (unless you need to use the `_` GET variable), but if you need to disable it you should set `cache: true` using `ajaxSetup`:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: true
});
```

Of course, as Ian mentions, this will affect every Ajax call on the page, so be aware of that if you have other Ajax calls. It might be better to refactor your code and use a more configurable function than `.load()`.

See a similar (opposite) question here: [Stop jQuery .load response from being cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168963/stop-jquery-load-response-from-being-cached)

Comment: I am using the ajaxForm plugin - and on success of this form submission is runs that code above. I've added the code you suggested and still no luck...

Comment: I would really **not** suggest using `$.ajaxSetup` for this. Any other AJAX requests on the page, in any variation, will have this applied to it. And anyways, you want **`cache: true`** if you don't want the `&_=124234` on the end

Comment: Yeah - Changed it to true in the ajaxForm itself. Thanks :D

Comment: @Ian You're right, `cache: true` is correct. Updated my answer.

Comment: I took back my downvote, but I still strongly agree with @Ian re `$.ajaxSetup`. Best not to muck with globals if you don't need to.