# JQUERY LOAD unable to load same html again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created an html page which renders differently depending on the parameter 'resourceType'.
ResourceType can be IO/CPU/STORAGE etc . I have adopted this design for reusability as we have same layout for all the charts except that the inputs to chart differs based on resourceType.

```
 <script>
    require(['../js/viewmodel/db-resource-analyze']);
</script>  

        <div class="oj-row" id="pageContent">


            <div class="topchartRegionDiv">
```

.....

```
            </div>
       </div>
```

Now I am loading this page from my HOME page which have vertical tabs (like a left side menu)
On click of a tab ,I load my page dynamically using jquery load

```
window.paramObj =
                 {
                    resType: "cpu"
                 };


$('#cpuContent').load("db-analytics-resources-home.html", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
                                    if (statusTxt == "success")
                                        alert("External content loaded successfully!");
                                    if (statusTxt == "error")
                                        alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
                                });
```

The next time user click on IO tab ...i do same operation but with different parameter

```
window.paramObj =
                 {
                    resType: "io"
                 };
$('#ioContent').load("db-analytics-resources-home.html", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
                                    if (statusTxt == "success")
                                        alert("External content loaded successfully!");
                                    if (statusTxt == "error")
                                        alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
                                });
```

The first load happens without any issues , but subsequent load do not happen and page comes as blank. 
I am suspecting the page is cached and not loaded. How to enforce reload skipping cache using JQUERY load. Any pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Stop jQuery .load response from being cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168963/stop-jquery-load-response-from-being-cached#answer-168977)

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```

As the guy mentions if the convenience functions like .load, .loadJSON, etc don't do what you need, use the .ajax function and you can find a lot of configuration options in there that will likely do what you need

Comment: Try what @Oleg suggests, this should also prevent the AJAX call from being cached.

Also are you building the jquery selector properly when you do $('#ioContent'), be sure you are not doing $('ioContent'), notice the missing #

Answer (score 0):

you can try this methode. this will prevent all caching

$('#ioContent').load("db-analytics-resources-home.html?"+Math.random(), function(){})

Comment: Thanks for response . I tried this too ...but no help .I could get this resolved by passing JS script as parameter to JQUERY load callback and invoking it there on load success.

Answer (score 0):

Many Thanks for all response . I could get this resolved by passing JS script as parameter to JQUERY load callback and invoking it there on successfully load of html doc .

smthing like this :

```
                        $('#' + resType + 'Content').load(url, function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
                                if (statusTxt == "success")
                                {

                                    alert("External content loaded successfully!...calling JS");
                                    new self.dbResourceAnalyze();
                                }
                                if (statusTxt == "error")
                                    alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);


                            });
```