# IE problems with Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I am running a PHP file so it's contents are in a div - then displaying the contents in a bootstrap modal. For some reason IE version 9 and 11 do not refresh the div and the modal shows old data. All other browsers work nicely.

```
function showRealSpadTable(realSpadDetails) {
        var tableDetails = realSpadDetails;

        $.post("realSpadTable.php", {tableDetails: tableDetails}, function () {    
                $("#realSpad").load("realSpadModal.php", function() {                             
                        $('#realSpadModal').modal('show');
                });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Maybe IE is caching the result of `$("#realSpad").load(...)`. Please check the answer in the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168963/stop-jquery-load-response-from-being-cached I think you have to use `$.ajax()` instead an set `cache` to `false`.

Comment: logical explanation but it still seems to have a problem. I've tried disabling the caching using the methods suggested.

Comment: Ok I have solved it by changing the browser history settings to check for newer versions of stored pages every time it loads a page.